# O que significa '~' na frente do construtor de uma classe C#

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, destrutor

Trabalhando em um projeto aqui na empresa, me deparei com alguns comandos que estão agora sendo mais utilizados (`yield`, `??`, `anonymous type`) mas até que entendi, porém um que me chamou a atenção por desconhecer o que é.

Alguém já viu o seguinte exemplo?

```cs
public Perfil {
    public ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    ...

    ~Perfil() {
        Usuarios = new HashSet<Usuarios>();
    }
}
```

Quem já viu e sabe a respeito, poderia passar uma breve explicação? É apenas curiosidade para entender melhor.

Existem outros similares?

Comment: Um pouco fora do escopo principal da pergunta, mas que pode ser do seu interesse saber, o operador `yield` deve ser entendido como um operador de **acumulação**. Por exemplo: `public IEnumerable<int> ListaDeNumeros() { for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { yield return i; } }` O código fará 100 returns, acumulando o resultado em uma espécie duma `List<int>` com os números de 1 a 100.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Sim, o yield conheci a pouco tempo e acho muito interessante a utilização dele, como eu falei é que realmente desde a primeira vez que comecei a programar a 4 anos atrás, creio que hoje deve ter sido a primeira vez que vi o destructor em C# rsrs..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Isso não é um construtor, mas sim um destrutor.

O destrutor é chamado quando a CLR verifica que não existem mais referências para o objeto, e então vai eliminá-lo da memória. Se houver um destrutor declarado na classe do objeto, então este será chamado para *"limpar"* o objeto, antes da memória ser devolvida para o sistema.

Agora, falando do seu exemplo, não está fazendo muito sentido. Geralmente no destrutor se faz a limpeza de recursos não-managed... mas no exemplo está sendo criado um novo objeto, o que pode até fazer sentido visto o contexto completo, mas é de certa forma um código muito *"suspeito"*.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação

Comment: Essa eu aprendi na faculdade, rs, achei que não ia levar nada na vida das coisas que aprendi em C, mas to vendo que não é bem assim XD

Answer (score 17):

Isto é um destrutor. A sintaxe é herdada do C++. Mas a semântica é bem diferente.

Na prática os destrutores não existem na linguagem. Para entender vou explicar dois outros conceitos.

## `Dispose()`

Este é um método disponível em todos os tipos que implementam a interface [`IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e permite que recursos sejam liberados quando o objeto não é mais necessário. A chamada do `Dispose()` pode ser feita manualmente a qualquer momento ou automaticamente com a utilização do *statement* `using`. A liberação de recursos são libera a memória. Apenas o *garbage collector* permite liberar a memória. Se um tipo não precisa ter recursos externos, ele é desnecessário.

## Finalize

Este é o método que realmente processo tudo o que é necessário no momento anterior a liberação da memória. Podemos dizer que ele é responsável pela liberação, embora de verdade quem faz isto é o *garbage collector*. Um `finalize()` está sempre disponível, até porque ele faz parte do tipo `Object` e na maior parte dos casos a implementação padrão do `Object` é suficiente.

## Destrutor

Você não consegue sobrepor um método `Finalize()` em seu tipo. O compilador não permite que você utilize sua própria implementação. Mas permite que o destrutor seja criado. E ele pode processar o que deseja no destrutor e chame o `Finalize()`. A implementação padrão do `Finalize` precisa estar disponível em todos os tipos.

Então o código

```
class Car {
    ~Car() { // destrutor
        // código de limpeza...
    }
}
```

é o mesmo que

```
protected override void Finalize() {
    try {
        // código de limpeza...
    } finally {
        base.Finalize();
    }
}
```

mas a segunda forma só pode ser gerada pelo compilador em substituição ao destrutor.

Portanto um destrutor em C# nem é executado logo após o objeto não ser mais necessário, nem tão pouco é executado na mesma *thread* e sim na *thread* do *garbage collector*. Existem uma série de problemas relacionados ao método de finalização que não fazem parte do escopo da pergunta. Finalizadores, mesmo que na forma de destrutor só devem ser personalizados quando o programador entende profundamente todas suas implicações.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Destructor.cs)