# Método para executar ao destruir instância de uma classe

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern

Eu tenho uma classe genérica de SQL, onde no construtor eu chamo um método que abre a conexão. Só que eu quero fechar essa conexão automaticamente também, sem precisar ter que criar um método que fecha a conexão e chamar ele dentro de vários outros métodos da classe. Veja abaixo:

```
public class SQL
{
      SQL(ObjConn obj)
      {
          AbrirConexao(obj);
      }

      public static void AbrirConexao(ObjConn objConn)
     {
         Conexao.ConnectionString = objConn.Acesso == "0" ? Utils.GetConnectionStringNerCard(objConn) : Utils.GetConnectionStringAutorizador(objConn);
         if (Conexao.State != ConnectionState.Open)
         Conexao.Open();
     }
 }
```

Vejam que eu crio o construtor e chamo o método de `AbrirConexão`.

Existe algum método nativo que ele é chamado automaticamente pelo .NET ao destruir a instancia de uma classe?

Comment: Creio que o garbage collector faça isso por você, de uma olhada neste link http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/66x5fx1b.aspx

Comment: @MeuChapeu, não sabia deste método "Destruidor". Conhecia o construtor. Mas o destruidor não. Valeu demais!

Comment: Pelo fato de se tratar de uma conexão, não é legal você manter a conexão aberta e só fechar quando o garbage collector remover o objeto. É mais interessante você implementar o Disposable Pattern. De uma olhada na respota do @bigown!

Comment: Estou vendo aqui. Vou usar o Disposable Pattern mesmo. Valeu @Renan.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Disposable Pattern

Sim, existe, chama-se [Disposable Pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Não é exatamente na destruição da instância porque em C# esta destruição não é determinística. Ou seja, só quando o *garbage collector* atuar é que a destruição realmente acontecerá, enquanto isto sua conexão continuará aberta e você não saberá porque dá problemas em outros lugares não relacionados.

Neste padrão você cria sua classe implementando a interface `IDisposable` (cria a implementação do método `Dispose()`) fazendo o que você deseja. Com o padrão implementado você pode chamar o método de encerramento quando você desejar. Implementá-lo corretamente não é muito simples mesmo que possa parecer. É fácil cometer erros que serão difíceis de resolver no futuro.

Mas não basta criar a classe desta forma, você precisa usar a classe do jeito certo para garantir que o `Dispose()` seja chamado mesmo que alguma exceção ocorra. Isto é trabalho para o [`using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

## Using

Este comando foi criado justamente para manipular o gerenciamento de recursos externos à aplicação (qualquer tipo) encerrando seu uso e existência quando você desejar sem correr riscos. Dá para fazer a mesma coisa manualmente. Mas é preciso saber o que está fazendo, qualquer deslise e você terá não só um vazamento de memória, mas um vazamento do recurso, mantendo ativo algo que não poderia mais estar neste estado.

O `using` cria um bloco e o tempo de vida do recurso aberto nele será justamente este bloco. Enquanto seu código estiver executando dentro deste bloco, a conexão estará aberta, quando sair deste bloco, não importa o motivo, a conexão será fechada. É bom ressaltar que se você chamar qualquer método dentro do bloco, você ainda estará dentro do bloco.

Num primeiro momento, antes de conhecer bem esse recurso, pode parecer mais complicado, mas manter a abertura e fechamento de forma independente pode causar pesadelos na sua aplicação a não ser que tenha um domínio que poucos desenvolvedores experientes têm.

Claro que é possível chamar o `Dispose()` manualmente. Mas em quase 100% dos casos fazer isto é um erro. E quando está certo quase sempre é dentro da própria classe.

## Destrutor

Existe ainda como fazer o mesmo através do método `Finalize()` ou o [método destrutor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9078/101) `~NomeDaClasse()` mas em geral é um erro usá-los. Há uma série de detalhes que fazem deles uma opção correta em casos bem limitados. Se você não sabe 100% como usá-los é porque não precisa deles.

## Recursos padrões do .NET já fazem isto para você

Na verdade, a [conexão que você está abrindo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/establishing-the-connection?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) já implementa a `IDisposable`, então se escrever o código do jeito correto, é provável que esta classe `SQL` nem deveria existir. Dê uma olhada em código de outras pessoas para ver como elas trabalham com isto.

Você precisa aprender usar os padrões da linguagem (`using`), caso contrário vai ficar reinventando a roda e muito provavelmente ela sairá quadrada. Fazer a roda redondinha, pelo menos neste caso, é bem complicado, se não tiver certeza que consegue, é melhor a roda pronta.

## Documentação

Eu estava procurando exemplos no site da Microsoft e fiquei de boca aberta porque eles postaram alguns que induzem à práticas ruins. Eu sei que é só um exemplo lá e que não traria consequências ruins, mas para quem é leigo, lê aquilo e acha que o correto é daquela forma para tudo.

Achei [exemplos de classe utilitária](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602043/how-to-manage-sql-connections-with-a-utility-class) para o que você quer. Não sei se ela serve exatamente aos seus propósitos, mas é o caminho.

Leia mais na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Enfim, o assunto é complexo, se você não se dedicar bastante em cima dele, vai causar um caos na sua aplicação.

Quando tiver um código mais pronto poste ele em outra pergunta e peça *peer review* de forma clara para ver se você está no caminho certo.

Outros recursos:

- [Implementando o padrão](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispose_pattern).
- [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P).
- Minha [resposta mais detalhada sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22305/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado @bigown.

Comment: @ThiagoHenrique Resolveu sua dúvida você pode aceitar uma das respostas com a mais correta. Acho que já viu no [tour] como se faz. Você pode votar em todas as perguntas e respostas do site que lhe ajudaram de alguma forma em qualquer assunto e acha que seria útil também para outras pessoas.

Answer (score 5):

Para que seu objetivo seja alcançado você precisará utilizar `using` e a interface `IDisposable` na seguinte abordagem:

Herde a sua classe de `IDisposable`, ou seja: `public class SQL : IDisposable` para que você possa implementar o método `public void Dispose()` e dentro desse método você irá colocar o trecho que precisa ser executado automaticamente.

```
public void Dispose()
{   
    if (Conexao.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        Conexao.Close();

    // outros códigos...
}
```

Quando for usar a classe `SQL` você terá que utilizar dentro do contexto de `using` para que ao final de tudo o método `Dispose()` seja chamado automaticamente.

Seria algo como:

```
using(SQL s = new SQL(ObjConn objConn))
{
    // faça o que tiver que fazer aqui
}

// após sair do contexto de 'using', o método Dispose será chamado automaticamente
```