# Qual a utilidade do using?

Tags: c#, .net, using

Minha dúvida é com relação a diferença entre:

```
//Bloco 1
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    //código
}

//Bloco 2
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    //código
}
```

No fundo parecem ser a mesma coisa. Existe alguma diferença?

Comment: http://cbsa.com.br/post/c---por-que-usar-using.aspx Acho que aqui tem uma boa explicação.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A utilização de `using` permite que as classes que implementem *IDisposable* sejam usadas de forma a garantir a execução do método `Dispose()` no fim da sua utilização, mesmo que lance uma exceção.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    //código
}
```

É equivalente a:

```
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    try
    {
        //código    
    }
    finally
    {
        if (memoryStream != null)
        {
            memoryStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Classes que implementam *IDisposable* normalmente alocam *unmanaged resources*, ou outros, que não serão libertados se o método `Dispose()` não for chamado.

Sempre que uma classe implemente *IDisposable* o método `Dispose()`deverá ser chamado de forma explicita ou de forma implícita recorrendo ao uso do bloco *using*.

Comment: `MemoryStream` nao aloca unmanaged resources, só aloca um `byte[]`. `FileStream` seria um exemplo melhor, porque aloca uma `SafeFileHandle`, que por sua vez contém um `IntPtr` (unmanaged).

Comment: Com isto não quero dizer que não se deva chamar `Dispose` numa `MemoryStream`. `IDisposable` não serve só para libertar unmanaged resources, serve para "limpar" o estado do objecto - a definição de "limpar" depende da implementação, e pode ter vários significados. Por essa razão, é boa prática chamar `Dispose` em todos os tipos que implementem `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 8):

A instrução **using** garante que o [Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) seja chamado, mesmo quando ocorrer uma exceção enquanto você está chamando métodos no objeto.

Você pode obter o mesmo resultado, colocando o objeto em um bloco try e depois chamar o Dispose em um bloco finally. Na verdade, isso é como a instrução using é traduzida pelo compilador.

```
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    try
    {
        //código
    }
    finally
    {
        if (memoryStream != null)
           ((IDisposable)memoryStream).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Respondendo a pergunta feita, a diferença entre os dois códigos é que o segundo vaza memória e recursos por algum tempo. Ou seja, o segundo código abre um mecanismo que usa recursos externos não gerenciados pelo *garbage collector*, e não fecha em momento algum, portanto ele fica disponível para uso por bastante tempo, mas provavelmente sem uso real. Então há desperdício de recursos, inclusive, eventualmente, de memória não gerenciada.

Não é que ele nunca será fechado. Quando o GC fizer uma coleta do objeto gerenciado que não está efetivamente em uso em outras partes do código, o fechamento será chamado, ou seja, o GC chamará um método chamado [`Dispose()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que faz o encerramento do objeto de forma adequada. Mas enquanto o GC não coletar o objeto ele ficará lá solto e desperdiçando.

O mais correto é o seu código chamar este método quando já terminou de usar o que queria e não precisa mais dele. Teoricamente poderia chamar ele de forma simples, porém se der uma exceção ele não seria chamado. Além disso pode ser que o objeto tenha sido anulado antes, então para fazer corretamente não é tão simples, teria que escrever [mais ou menos este código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145858/101):

```
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    try {
        //código    
    } finally {
        if (memoryStream != null) {
            memoryStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Como é tedioso e é fácil cometer algum erro, tem um *syntax sugar* que faz isso para você, e é justamente a primeira sintaxe que usou na pergunta, o tal do `using` que faz para você o [*disposable pattern*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41175/101) que [chama o método sem você precisar fazê-lo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173210/101).

Nas últimas versões do C# não é mais necessário marcar um bloco de `using`. Quase sempre você quer fazer a liberação do recurso ao fim do bloco onde ele foi declarado, então em vez de criar um bloco novo só para ele, declara a variável diretamente e o bloco passa ser todo o atual, o que muitas vezes é o próprio método, assim:

```
using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
```

Ou melhor ainda:

```
using MemoryStream memoryStream = new();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/BlockUsing.cs).

[Nem sempre ele deve ser usado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422717/101), ao contrário da crença popular.

Veja mais:

- [Quais tipos de recursos são liberados em uma declaração "using"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101)
- [Como funciona a relação do "using" e do garbage collector do .NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422625/101)
- [Devo sempre utilizar Dispose()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101)

Comment: Só um detalhe, o novo using não necessariamente vai chamar o Dispose no fim do método mas sim no fim do bloco atual, por exemplo se você usar ele dentro de um if ele vai chamar o dispose no final do bloco if, da pra conferir isso usando o sharplab.io para ver o código gerado pelo compilador, fiz um exemplo simples pra demonstrar http://shorturl.at/ikstG

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa sim, foi um lapso meu não colocar da forma mais correta, obrigado, está ok agora.