# Por que ocorre o erro unreachable code detected em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

```
    public Boolean LogarUsuario(string Pnome, string Psenha)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conexao = new OleDbConnection(Conexao.stringConn))
        {
            conexao.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Nome = ? AND Senha = ?";
            cmd.Connection = conexao;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nome", OleDbType.WChar).Value = Pnome;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Senha", OleDbType.WChar).Value = Psenha;

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {
                reader.Read();
                Nome = String.Format("{0}", reader[1]);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return false;
            }
            conexao.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Onde está dando o erro? Tente ser o mais específico possível. Você pode melhorar sua pergunta clicando em [edit].

Comment: A execução nunca vai chegar ao  `conexao.Close();`, pois ela executa o return de qualquer modo antes disso.

Comment: @Mateus qual é a intenção de retornar verdeiro ou falso? É dizer se o usuário está *logado*, ou dizer que o método executou certo ou não?

Comment: @Mateus Alguma das respostas resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 8):

Não se preocupe, a conexão será fechada pelo [`using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66230/101). Ainda bem, porque se ele não tivesse sido usado, teria problemas mais sérios no código. Não sei se tem outros problemas por que não vi tudo, só posso falar deste método isoladamente.

Do jeito que estava fazendo dava erro porque nada pode ser executado depois de um `return` incondicional, que é o caso do `try-catch`. Então como uma execução pode ser feita depois que já saiu do método? Normalmente quando você quer garantir que a execução seja feita sempre ao antes de sair do método pode usar um `try-finally`, que é exatamente o que o `using` faz para recursos que precisam ser fechados.

Mas algo que eu acho estranho é a exceção ser responsável por determinar se o usuário pode *logar* ou não, parece muito errado, ou pelo menos pouco robusto, ainda mais [capturando `Exception` que neste caso não só é arriscado, dá toda pinta de ser bem errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101), de ser quase certo que algo errado acontecerá e causará falhas indesejáveis. Eu tiraria isto.

E não usaria `Boolean` isto não é C# "de verdade", prefira `bool` :)

Idealmente o [`OleDbDataReader`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0) deveria ser "protegido" pelo `using` também. Ele sofre do mesmo problema da conexão, é um recurso externo que precisa ser fechado.

Além disto, me preocupa a variável `cmd` não ser declarada dentro deste método. Pode existir um motivo para isto, mas duvido que seja o certo.

Eu vou entender que a exceção está sendo usada para detectar se o usuário está logado ou não. Se não for o caso não tem porque pegar esta exceção e retornar o resultado.

Vou colocar uma forma que parece ficar melhor:

```
public bool LogarUsuario(string Pnome, string Psenha) {
    using (var conexao = new OleDbConnection(Conexao.stringConn)) {
        conexao.Open();
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Nome = ? AND Senha = ?", conexao);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nome", OleDbType.WChar).Value = Pnome;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Senha", OleDbType.WChar).Value = Psenha;
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            reader.Read();
            if (reader.HasRows) {
                Nome = reader[1];
            }
            return reader.HasRows;
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/UnreachedCode.cs).

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54621/discussion-on-answer-by-bigown-por-que-ocorre-o-erro-unreachable-code-detected-e)

Answer (score 6):

Esse aviso/erro indica que existe código que nunca será executado qualquer que seja o caminho de execução.

Repare que, quando a execução chega ao bloco `try/catch`, tanto seja uma excepção lançada ou não, será encontrado um `return`, não sendo por isso possível executar a linha `conexao.Close();`.

Ela também não é necessária porque a *OleDbConnection* é instanciada dentro do bloco *using*, o compilador [criará o código necessário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66232/2541) para que ela seja fechada, haja ou não uma excepção.