# Duas combobox dependentes usando linq to sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, combobox

Como faço para preencher duas combobox's com linq to sql onde numa combobox por exemplo tenho paises e noutra tenho as cidades? Como fazer elas mudarem os valores automaticamente? Deixo a imagem em baixo de como preenchi uma, se houver algum erro e quiserem dar alguma sugestão agradeço muito. Obrigado a todos :)

[image: Assim Foi como preenchi uma combobox]

Comment: Uma coisa importante: não publique uma screenshot do código, o código propriamente dito (e bem formatado) fica muito mais fácil de ler, sem contar que existem pessoas que usam o site e têm algum tipo de bloqueio (como pode ver as imagens ficam em outro domínio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alguns pontos antes de resolver o problema.

1. Sua premissa de como preencher o combo não está errada, mas não é a melhor forma de fazer isso. Não é necessário iterar o itens e adicioná-los um a um, é possível usar uma coleção como `DataSource` do ComboBox.
2. Você só está adicionando o nome dos itens no ComboBox, isso é errado (volta ao caso acima, use a propriedade `DataSource` e popule o ComboBox com uma lista de objetos).
3. Sempre deve-se dar `Dispose` no contexto depois de fazer alguma operação com o banco de dados, mesmo não tendo o resto do código, me parece que isso não está sendo feito. (No meu código isso é feito com o `using`, você pode ver mais sobre ele [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66230/qual-a-utilidade-do-using).

Enfim, pra resolver seu problema, você precisará usar o evento `SelectedValueChanged` do ComboBox (pode ser qualquer um que dispare quando mudar o item selecionado, eu prefiro este).

Exemplo de como ficaria seu código (o exemplo usa países, estados e cidades, mas a lógica é a mesma):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    cbPais.DisplayMember = 
    cbEstado.DisplayMember = 
    cbCidade.DisplayMember = "Nome";
    //Define qual propriedade dos objetos serão mostradas no combo

    cbPais.ValueMember =
    cbEstado.ValueMember =
    cbCidade.ValueMember = "Id";
    //Define qual propriedade vai funcionar como valor do item selecionado

    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        cbPais.DataSource = db.Paises.ToList();
    }
}

private void cbPais_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var paisId = Convert.ToInt32(cbPais.SelectedValue); 
    //Pega o ValueMember do item selecionado

    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        cbEstado.DataSource = db.Estados.Where(x => x.PaisId == paisId).ToList();
    }
}

private void cbEstado_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var estadoId = Convert.ToInt32(cbEstado.SelectedValue);
    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        cbCidade.DataSource = db.Cidades.Where(c => c.EstadoId == estadoId).ToList();
    }
}
```