# Try catch pode ser substituido por using?

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch, using

Eu sempre usei os blocos `try`, `catch` e `finally` quando programava em Java, e quando mudei para C# notei que alguns códigos trocam o `try/catch` por `using`.

Exemplo:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("abc.txt", FileMode.Create))
{
    // Algum código...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sim, o mais adequado é fazer com o [`using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) mesmo. Esse código equivale a isto:

```
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("abc.txt", FileMode.Create);
    try {
       // Algum código...
    } finally {
        if (fs != null)
            ((IDisposable)fs).Dispose();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Using.cs).

Equivale mais ou menos ao [`try-resource` do Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Em alguns casos pode ser mais adequado fazer manualmente, por exemplo quando precisa de um `catch` específico para esse recurso, ou precisar fazer algo além do `dispose()` no bloco do `finally`. Nesses casos é importante fazer a disposição de forma adequada no `finally`, conforme mostrado acima.

Note que o `using` nada tem a ver com `try-catch`, como perguntado, e sim com `try-finally`.

Comment: O using é como se fosse um try automático, qualquer instancia que pertença a interface idisposable ele fecha automaticamente no final, vejo que é só uma forma de programar mais rápido e limpo.

Comment: Isso mesmo, é açúcar sintático.

Answer (score 5):

Você troca apenas o `try/finally` por `using`. Onde houver `try/catch` continua sendo da mesma maneira, pois o `using` não trata exceção, ele apenas garante que um objeto só irá existir dentro de um escopo - `using {...}` - definido.