# Nem todos os caminhos retornam valor

Tags: c#, return

[image: Erro sendo mostrado]

O evento `Cadastrar` está aparecendo com o erro.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CamadaModelo;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using CamadaControle;

namespace CamadaControle
    {
    public class ctlTarefas
    {
        public bool Cadastrar(mdlTarefas _mdlTarefas)
        {
            try
            {
                string conexaoMSAccess = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexaoMSAccess"].ToString();
                OleDbConnection conexaodb = new OleDbConnection(conexaoMSAccess);
                conexaodb.Open();

                string query = "INSERT INTO tbl_tarefas (nome, descrição, data) VALUES (@Nome, @Descrição, @Data)";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conexaodb);

                var pmtNome = cmd.CreateParameter();
                pmtNome.ParameterName = "@Nome";
                pmtNome.DbType = DbType.String;
                pmtNome.Value = _mdlTarefas.nome;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pmtNome);

                var pmtDescricao = cmd.CreateParameter();
                pmtDescricao.ParameterName = "@Descrição";
                pmtDescricao.DbType = DbType.String;
                pmtDescricao.Value = _mdlTarefas.nome;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pmtDescricao);

                var pmtData = cmd.CreateParameter();
                pmtData.ParameterName = "@Data";
                pmtData.DbType = DbType.String;
                pmtData.Value = _mdlTarefas.nome;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pmtData);

                if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                {
                    conexaodb.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    conexaodb.Close();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Erro ao inserir informações!" + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Precione inicio");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Favor ajustar a sua pergunta. Ela tem falhas de formatação. Coloque o erro em texto e não em imagem.

Comment: Ajustado, obrigado pela dica

Comment: @PatryckDalpont A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, retire esse `try-catch` do código, ele não está fazendo nada útil, então é melhor retirá-lo, só coloque um `catch` se puder se recuperar do erro ou fazer algo útil.

Depois [use o `using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259882/101) para gerenciar um recurso, assim faz o fechamento do recurso da forma correta, esta está errada. [Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145858/101). E outra pergunta é sobre o [Método para executar ao destruir instância de uma classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41175/101).

E simplifique o código, não falarei de tudo, mas todo o `if` pode ser substituído por

```
return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/Found.cs).

Mais nada.

Comment: Olá Maniero, se eu tirar o try não vai interferir no processo de acesso a conexão do banco de dados do access que tenho?

Comment: Não, porque ele não está fazendo nada útil. Nunca use o recursos sem saber para que ele serve. Este você ainda não sabe. Só o use quando aprender. Faça o que eu falei na resposta.