# Se eu retornar algo dentro de um using, os recursos serão liberados?

Tags: c#

Eu sei que o `using` é utilizado para liberar (dar um `dispose`) recursos. A minha dúvida é no seguinte caso:

```
public void FuncNaoFazNada()
{
    using(var acd = new AlgumaClasseIDisposable())
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, os recursos utilizados por acd serão dispensados? Ou a quebra de fluxo manterá os recursos alocados?

Comment: Relacionada(duplicata?) com [Qual a utilidade do using?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66230/2541)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é um *syntax-sugar* com funcionamento exatamente igual ao try-finally:

```
var acd = new AlgumaClasseIDisposable();
try
{
    return FazAlgumaCoisa(acd);
}
finally
{
    acd.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A resposta é: será liberado sim.

o `using` no C# é um açúcar sintático, que nada mais é que um `try ... finally` no final, onde este seu código:

```
public void FuncNaoFazNada()
{
    using(var acd = new AlgumaClasseIDisposable())
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Será na verdade:

```
public void FuncNaoFazNada()
{
    var acd = new AlgumaClasseIDisposable();
    try{
        return;
    }
    finally{
        acd.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Então apesar do `return` dentro do `try`, ele vai sempre executar o bloco de código do `finally`.

> Dica: Para entender melhor o funcionamento implemente a segunda forma do código e o *debug* linha a linha. Assim entenderá como é o fluxo de execução.