# Exclusão negada de arquivo no C#

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo

Estou usando a seguinte linha para criar e gravar:

```
File.WriteAllText(caminho + cliente, xml);
```

Nele eu gravo um XML e depois eu trato da seguinte forma:

```
if (File.Exists(caminho + cliente))
            {
                XmlTextReader xmlLer = new XmlTextReader(caminho + cliente);
                bool ultimaTag = false;

                while (xmlLer.Read())
                {
                    switch (xmlLer.NodeType)
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            nomeElemento = xmlLer.Name.ToString();
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Text:
                            switch (nomeElemento)
                            {
                                case "id_parcela":
                                    objPedidoParcelas.IdParcela = int.Parse(xmlLer.Value);
                                    break;
                                case "id_pedido":
                                    objPedidoParcelas.IdPedido = int.Parse(xmlLer.Value);
                                    break;
                                case "forma_pagamento":
                                    objPedidoParcelas.FormaPagamento = Utils.RemoverAcentos(xmlLer.Value.ToString().ToUpper());
                                    break;
                                case "data_vencimento":
                                    objPedidoParcelas.DataVencimento = xmlLer.Value.ToString();
                                    break;
                                case "valor":
                                    objPedidoParcelas.Valor = xmlLer.Value.ToString();
                                    break;
                                case "data_pagamento":
                                    objPedidoParcelas.DataPagamento = xmlLer.Value.ToString();
                                    break;
                                case "data_confirmacao":
                                    objPedidoParcelas.DataConfirmacao = xmlLer.Value.ToString();
                                    break;
                                case "valor_pago":
                                    objPedidoParcelas.ValorPago = xmlLer.Value.ToString();
                                    break;
                                case "local_pagamento":
                                    objPedidoParcelas.LocalPagamento = Utils.RemoverAcentos(xmlLer.Value.ToString().ToUpper());
                                    break;
                                case "observacao":
                                    objPedidoParcelas.Observacao = Utils.RemoverAcentos(xmlLer.Value.ToString().ToUpper());
                                    break;
                                case "id_forma_pagamento":
                                    objPedidoParcelas.IdFormaPagamento = int.Parse(xmlLer.Value.ToString());
                                    break;
                                case "qt_parcelas":
                                    objPedidoParcelas.QtdParcelas = int.Parse(xmlLer.Value.ToString());
                                    break;
                                case "status":
                                    objPedidoParcelas.Status = Utils.RemoverAcentos(xmlLer.Value.ToString().ToUpper());
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Logo tento excluir o arquivo:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(caminho);

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete();
}
```

Fala que o arquivo está sendo utilizado por outro processo.

O arquivo não existe, ele é criado com o objetivo de gravar o XML e depois lê-lo e em seguida excluir.

Comment: Normalmente você não tem permissão para fazer isso, o arquivo está aberto ou algo assim. Pode ser que não fechou o arquivo que acabou de gravar. `Thread.Sleep(1000)` isso parece uma gambiarra. O fato é que a gente não sabe o que acontece, pelo menos não só com essas informações.

Comment: sim é uma gambiarra.. para ver se fecha o arquivo

Comment: Arquivos não se fecham sozinhos. Não adianta fazer macumba.

Comment: Verdade... têm alguma sugestão?

Comment: Qual a pasta que você está criando o arquivo?

Comment: é uma pasta dentro da pasta Bin do projeto do Visual Studio.. se chama XML

Comment: Você tenta excluir logo depois de criar?

Comment: Não... algumas coisas depois.. mas que não tem nada a ver com o arquivo.. eu crio... gravo um xml, uso o arquivo para outra coisa e tento excluir

Comment: Precisa ir fechando o problema, descobrir qual é o arquivo que está causando isso, verificar se ele está aberto no sistema operacional, quem tem ele aberto, é sua aplicação? ver porque ele está aberto. Ir executando e ver onde está o problema. Esse código está correto, há problema em outro lugar.

Comment: Usa o arquivo na aplicação mesmo? Provavelmente o problema tá nesse "*uso o arquivo para outra coisa e tento excluir*".

Comment: Coloque **todo** o código de **`if (File.Exists(...))`**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema é que o arquivo está sendo usado pelo `XmlTextReader`, nessa linha

```
XmlTextReader xmlLer = new XmlTextReader(caminho + cliente);
```

Você precisa liberá-lo usando o [`Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc310545(v=vs.110).aspx). Adicione essa linha no final do código:

```
xmlLer.Dispose();
```

Também é possível usar o bloco `using` para evitar de esquecer o `Dispose()`. Com o `using` é possível ter **certeza** de que o *stream* (o "arquivo") será fechado, mesmo que ocorra alguma exceção no bloco, porque, por "baixo dos panos" ele nada mais é que um `try { } finally { recurso.Dispose(); }` — é possível ver mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66230/18246)

```
using(XmlTextReader xmlLer = new XmlTextReader(caminho + cliente))
{
   // ao final do bloco o arquivo será "liberado"   
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Pelo que foi postado o arquivo provavelmente está aberto. A linha que abre:

```
XmlTextReader xmlLer = new XmlTextReader(caminho + cliente);
```

Não fecha o arquivo.

O correto é abrir com [`using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), algo assim:

```
using (xmlLer = new XmlTextReader(caminho + cliente)) {
    //faz tudo o que precisa
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/XmlTextReader.cs).

Só assim garante que o fechamento ocorre. Sempre que a classe implementar a interface `IDisposable` deve fazer desta forma.

Tem [exemplos na documentação da `XmlReader`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) (da qual a `XmlTextReader` herda).

Tem uma [pergunta com mais detalhes sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101).