# Erro ao desconectar do PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, conexão, npgsql

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação em C# com utilização do SGDB PostgreSQL, porém sempre quando fecho a conexão dá o seguinte erro:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Estou utilizando o `mono.security` e o `npgsql2` porém não consegui adicionar o atual.

```
 //Inserir registros

public void ExecutarSQL(string sql)
{
    try
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection pgsqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
        {
            //Abra a conexão com o PgSQL                  
            pgsqlConnection.Open();
            string cmdInserir = sql;

            using (NpgsqlCommand pgsqlcommand = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdInserir, pgsqlConnection))
            {
                int i = pgsqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NpgsqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("npgsql");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("exp");
    }
    finally
    {
        MessageBox.Show("fecha");
        pgsqlConnection.Close();
    }     
}
```

No caso em questão eu consigo passar uma SQL para a função (*insert*) e ele insere o dado porém quando cai no **`finally`** e chega no  `pgsqlConnection.Close()` aparece o erro informado acima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que no momento do `finally` a variável `pgsqlConnection` está nula porque o `using` se encarrega de fazer `Dispose` da variável pra você.

Diretamente falando, não é necessário essa operação no bloco `finally`, uma vez que o `using` já faz isso.

Veja essa pergunta para entender sobre o `using`: [Qual a utilidade do using?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66230/18246)

O código deveria ser:

```
public void ExecutarSQL(string sql)
{
    try
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection pgsqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
        {
            //Abra a conexão com o PgSQL                  
            pgsqlConnection.Open();
            string cmdInserir = sql;

            using (NpgsqlCommand pgsqlcommand = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdInserir, pgsqlConnection))
            {
                int i = pgsqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NpgsqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("npgsql");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("exp");
    }
    finally
    {
        MessageBox.Show("fecha");
    }     
}
```

Comment: Consegui entender a finalidade do using, obrigado!