# criar um arquivo com o conteúdo em C# e salvar em uma pasta no computador

Tags: c#, arquivo

Preciso criar um relatório e salvar esse relatório em uma pasta dentro do disco C: do computador, estou só conseguindo salvar o arquivo sem o conteúdo e com o nome em branco.

O código de salvar:

```
string folder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Relatorios"] + usuario;
string arquivo = folder + @"\" + nomearquivo;

if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(arquivo + ".txt " + relatorio);
}

if (!File.Exists(arquivo))
{
    File.Create(arquivo+".txt " + relatorio);
}               
else
{
    File.Delete(arquivo);
    File.Create(arquivo + ".txt " + relatorio);
}
```

Comment: Pode ser um exemplo com qualquer conteúdo?

Comment: pode ser sim...

Comment: Douglas, alguma das respostas solucionou seu problema?

Comment: Foi sim, so nao consigo salvar com o relatorio

Comment: Ok, então você pode marcar a resposta que solucionou o seu problema como correta usando o **✓** do lado esquerdo dela, certo? Sobre o novo problema, você pode abrir uma nova pergunta a qualquer momento se estiver precisando de ajuda.

Comment: muito bom, o problema é que o arquivo não atualiza conforme você adiciona caracteres

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tem vários probleminhas aí. Dei uma melhorada no seu código num geral.

1. Use [`Path.Combine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) ao invés de concatenar as strings com a barra invertida (isto é mais uma dica).
2. Não precisa verificar se o diretório existe antes de [`Directory.CreateDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) por que este método só cria o arquivo se ele não existir.
3. Não é necessário excluir o arquivo para recriá-lo. O método [`File.Create()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.file.create(v=vs.110).aspx) cria um arquivo se este não existir, caso o arquivo com este nome já existia, ele será sobrescrito.
4. **Cuidado com *streams* abertos**.

   `File.Create()` vai retornar um `FileStream`, este `FileStream` não está sendo fechado e você **precisa tomar cuidado com isto**. Por isso eu coloquei [`Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) depois do `Create()`.

   Leia sobre isto em: [Qual a utilidade do using?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66230/18246), [Quais tipos de recursos são liberados em uma declaração "using"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/18246), [Devo sempre utilizar Dispose?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/18246)
5. Faltou escrever o conteúdo do arquivo. O método `Create()` recebe apenas o nome do arquivo, você está concatenando o que deveria ser o conteúdo junto com o nome.

   No meu exemplo, usei [`WriteAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx) para escrevê-lo. Ele recebe como parâmetro um `IEnumerable<string>` e faz com que cada elemento desta coleção seja uma linha do arquivo. Usei este método porque é muito mais simples e não corre o risco de vazamento de recursos.

---

O código:

Supondo que `relatorio` seja uma coleção de `string` (array, lista, etc.).

```
List<string> relatorio = /*Fazer algo para carregar o relatório*/;

string folder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Relatorios"] + usuario;;
string arquivo = Path.Combine(folder, "arquivo.txt");
        
Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

File.Create(arquivo).Dispose();

File.WriteAllLines(arquivo, relatorio);
```

Comment: sua resposta me ajudou numa duvida minha, porem dessa forma o arquivo é criado dentro do servidor, teria como criar na maquina local do cliente ?

Comment: @Desalex Numa aplicação web é impossível. O que você pode fazer é gerar um arquivo no servidor e devolver pro cliente para que o usuário faça download.

Comment: como esse cara fez nesse exemplo desse video ai -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJRiGGgDEpE eu preciso disso, "fazer o download do arquivo criado" e nao estou conseguindo, fiz igual ele e o meu nao baixa nada, nao acontece nada.

Comment: @Desalex Abre uma pergunta então, cara.

Comment: ja ta aberta, é que ngm respondeu, porem preciso muito disso :(

Comment: @Desalex Procurei no seu perfil e não encontrei, se mandar o link eu tento responder...

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
    if (!File.Exists(path)) 
    {
        // Create a file to write to.
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) 
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Hello");
            sw.WriteLine("And");
            sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
        }   
    }
```