# Erro com View retornando um arquivo txt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou usando o seguinte código em meu `Controller`:

```
public ActionResult geraBpa()
{
    var caminho = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content");
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter($"{caminho}/BPA.txt");
    List<bpac> listaBpac = pegaBpac();

    int linhaTexto = 1;
    int linhaItem = 1;

    foreach (bpac linha in listaBpac)
    {
        file.WriteLine(
        "02" +
        linha.cnes +
        linha.cmp + //competencia
        linha.cbo +
        string.Format("{0:000}", linhaTexto) + string.Format("{0:00}", linhaItem) +
        linha.pa +
        "000" +
        string.Format("{0:000000}", linha.quant) +
        "EXT"
        );

        linhaItem++;
        if (linhaItem > 99)
        {
            linhaItem = 1;
            linhaTexto++;
        }
    }

    linhaTexto++;
    linhaItem = 1;

    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($"{caminho}/BPA.txt");
    string fileName = "myfile.ext";
    return File(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

Estou recebendo erro nessa linha:

> byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($"{caminho}/BPA.txt");

O erro diz que o arquivo `BPA.txt` está aberto. Quando fui até a pasta, vi que o mesmo nem foi criado corretamente.

Alguma ajuda?

Comment: Porfavor, poderia postar o erro que está dando ?

Comment: O arquivo é muito grande? Essa resposta do SO em inglês sugere que existe uma limitação de leitura utilizando esse método: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030847/best-way-to-read-a-large-file-into-a-byte-array-in-c. Considere utilizar um FileStream.

Comment: Humm no seu código não estou vendo fechamento do arquivo após sua abertura, talvez seja isso

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Arquivo txt abre no navegador ao invés de ser efetuado o download](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231227/arquivo-txt-abre-no-navegador-ao-inv%c3%a9s-de-ser-efetuado-o-download)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É exatamente este o problema, o arquivo já está aberto quando é feita a tentativa de leitura.

Seu código abre um `StreamWriter` e não o fecha. Você pode usar o método `Dispose` ou colocar o código que usa a variável `file` dentro de um `using`. Você pode ler sobre o `using` em [Qual a utilidade do using?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66230/18246)

Eu seguiria pelo segundo caminho, o código ficaria assim

```
var caminho = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content");
using(StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter($"{caminho}/BPA.txt"))
{
    List<bpac> listaBpac = pegaBpac();

    int linhaTexto = 1;
    int linhaItem = 1;

    foreach (bpac linha in listaBpac)
    {
        file.WriteLine(
        "02" +
        linha.cnes +
        linha.cmp + //competencia
        linha.cbo +
        string.Format("{0:000}", linhaTexto) + string.Format("{0:00}", linhaItem) +
        linha.pa +
        "000" +
        string.Format("{0:000000}", linha.quant) +
        "EXT"
        );

        linhaItem++;
        if (linhaItem > 99)
        {
            linhaItem = 1;
            linhaTexto++;
        }
    }
}

linhaTexto++;
linhaItem = 1;

byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($"{caminho}/BPA.txt");
string fileName = "myfile.ext";
return File(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```

Comment: Oi, o código funcionou, porém abre na tela ao invés de fazer o download. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Sim. Algumas sugestões. Não acha melhor abrir outra pergunta? Pra ser sincero, acho importante até porque eu gostaria de ter esse assunto catalogado em algum lugar.

Comment: Blz, abrirei sim.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231227/arquivo-txt-abre-no-navegador-ao-inv%c3%a9s-de-ser-efetuado-o-download