# Arquivo txt abre no navegador ao invés de ser efetuado o download

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Uso o seguinte código para gerar um arquivo txt e enviá-lo à minha `View`:

```
 public ActionResult geraBpa(){
    var caminho = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content");
    using(StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter($"{caminho}/BPA.txt"))
    {
        List<bpac> listaBpac = pegaBpac();

        int linhaTexto = 1;
        int linhaItem = 1;

        foreach (bpac linha in listaBpac)
        {
            file.WriteLine(
            "02" +
            linha.cnes +
            linha.cmp + //competencia
            linha.cbo +
            string.Format("{0:000}", linhaTexto) + string.Format("{0:00}", linhaItem) +
            linha.pa +
            "000" +
            string.Format("{0:000000}", linha.quant) +
            "EXT"
            );

            linhaItem++;
            if (linhaItem > 99)
            {
                linhaItem = 1;
                linhaTexto++;
            }
        }
    }

    linhaTexto++;
    linhaItem = 1;

    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($"{caminho}/BPA.txt");
    string fileName = "myfile.ext";
    return File(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

O mesmo está funcionando corretamente, porém, ao invés de ser efetuado o download, ele abre na tela do navegador.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Italo posta o cabeçalho da sua Action por gentileza.

Comment: seria isso? `public ActionResult geraBpa()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um *header* pra forçar este download

```
// [...] Resto do código

string fileName = "myfile.ext";
var disposition = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = fileName,
    Inline = false, // <- Isso força o download
};

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", disposition.ToString());

return File(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```

Comment: alterei, mas não funcionou

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo Deve ser por causa do mime type usado, tenta usar um de texto.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que assim resolveria seu problema:

```
try
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + _Filename);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Word");
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", _FileLength_in_bytes);
    Response.BinaryWrite(_Filedata_bytes);
    Response.End();
}
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{ }
finally
{
}
```

Comment: onde eu incluo esse código?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo você precisa adaptar ao seu código claro kkkk, mas mesmo assim coloquei com um _na frente de cada local aonde você ira colocar seu código