# Porque usar o bloco using no ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework

O bloco `using {}` funciona da mesma maneira tanto em aplicações web como em Desktops no sentido de quando utilizamos ele no `controller`? É uma boa pratica declarar ele nas ações que existe contato com o `database` Segue exemplos, qual deles seria uma boa pratica?

```
public class UsuarioController : Controller
{
private EntidadesDCSystem db = new EntidadesDCSystem();

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Adicionar(Usuario usuario)
   {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Usuario.Add(usuario);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(usuario);
    }
```

Ou:

```
public class UsuarioController : Controller
{

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Adicionar(Usuario usuario)
   {
      using (EntidadesDCSystem db = new EntidadesDCSystem())
      {
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
             db.Usuario.Add(usuario);
             db.SaveChanges();
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
           }

           return View(usuario);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### O bloco `using {}` funciona da mesma maneira tanto em aplicações web como em Desktops no sentido de quando utilizamos ele no *controller*?

Sim.

### Sobre os exemplos

Este aqui é bom quando você possui várias *Actions* no *Controller*:

```
public class UsuarioController : Controller
{
    private EntidadesDCSystem db = new EntidadesDCSystem();
    ...
```

O ciclo de vida de um *Controller* começa e termina dentro de uma requisição. Como `DbContext` implementa `IDisposable`, naturalmente que, ao encerrar o ciclo de vida, sua conexão com o banco de dados e outros dados serão descartados graciosamente.

`using` também faz isso: ele obriga o desenvolvedor a implementar `IDisposable` no objeto envolvido no `using`, ou seja, de ter um procedimento correto de descarte do objeto.

No *Controller*, pouco muda se você usa o contexto como objeto privado ou dentro de um bloco `using`, dado que um *Controller* é um objeto com um ciclo de vida muito curto, que não fica muito tempo em memória.

Answer (score 6):

> O bloco using {} funciona da mesma maneira tanto em aplicações web como em Desktops no sentido de quando utilizamos ele no controller?

**Sim**, funciona da mesma maneira.

O `using` nada mais é do que um `try finally`, onde no bloco `finally` é chamado o `Dispose()` do objeto, logo isso só dá certo com objetos que implementem `IDisposable`.

Fazer isso

```
using (EntidadesDCSystem db = new EntidadesDCSystem())
{
}
```

É a mesma coisa que fazer

```
EntidadesDCSystem db;
try
{
    db = new EntidadesDCSystem();
}
finally
{
    db.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Quando você utiliza a instrução `using`, você está dizendo ao compilador que o recurso que você esta utilizando não será mais utilizado após o fechamento da chave, isso garante que o objeto foi para o **Garbage Collector** e que o método `Dispose()` do objeto foi chamado.

No caso de contexto (EntityFramework), conexões a banco de dados e etc, o método `Dispose()` é onde os recursos utilizados pela classe de conexão são liberados da memória.

Um outro benefício é garantir que o objeto referenciado seja utilizado apenas naquele pedaço de código, impedindo que o mesmo seja referenciado depois de ter sido descartado (quando gera um NullReferenceException).

Em alguns casos isso pode gerar um ganho de desempenho, mais no caso de controllers o ganho não é muito grande, visto que o ciclo de vida de aplicações asp.net é muito curto (como disse o Cigano, começa e termina em uma requisição).

Vide a referência da Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Depende muito. O *Controller* normalmente é descartado bem rapidamente, porque só existe dentro do ciclo de vida da requisição, então esse ganho de desempenho é muito pequeno.

Comment: Realmente Cigano, este ponto de vista é válido, mais um outro benefício importante da utilização do using é garantir que o objeto seja utilizado somente onde é necessário, se você tentar utilizar o objeto fora do using o compilador nem compila e gera um erro. Isso impede de que alguém que pegou o código depois tente acessá-lo mais a frente.

Comment: Sim, mas vamos supor um *Controller* grande, ok? Sei lá, com 15 *Actions*. Você teria que declarar o bloco 15 vezes. Não tem muito fundamento prático. Além disso, como o `dispose` do *Controller* faz dispose em tudo que implementa `IDisposable`, o `dispose` do contexto vai acabar acontecendo de qualquer forma.

Comment: Faz sentido, mais o importante é conhecer o conceito e aplicar da melhor forma. Eu posso ter um controller com 15 actions, mais somente em uma trabalhar diretamente o banco, neste caso não faria sentido instanciar o contexto e dar dispose. Cada caso é um caso, mais a sua resposta é mais aplicável ao conceito da pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Especialmente este `using` deve ser usado em qualquer código C#. Ele garante a liberação de recursos e é essencial para evitar problemas de vazamento de recursos. Isto é um recurso da linguagem, não é algo que foi feito para desktop ou web. Use sempre que o objeto use algum recurso externo que precise ser liberado.

Mas neste caso a liberação do recurso ocorrerá rapidamente, então o seu uso pode ser dispensado, simplificando o código.

Ler a documentação é necessário para saber quando usar. Algumas ferramentas, como o Resharper, como alertar quando esqueceu de fazer isto. Tudo que adote a interface `IDisposable` deve usar o `using` ou outra forma que o simule, afinal internamente ele é apenas um `try-finally`.

Existe outro `using` para "importar" *namespaces*, que também é útil em qualquer tipo de aplicação. Apesar de ser a mesma palavra, os usos são bem diferentes.

Algumas leituras que podem ajudar:

- [Quando é recomendável que uma classe implemente IDisposable?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98341/101)
- [Devo sempre utilizar Dispose()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101)
- [Método para executar ao destruir instância de uma classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41175/101)
- [Liberar memória de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/414237/101)
- [Quais tipos de recursos são liberados em uma declaração "using"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101)
- [Para que serve uma implementação explícita de interface em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133957/101)
- [Quando devo usar GC.SuppressFinalize()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102609/101)
- [Método Dispose()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173210/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O que tem errado aqui?

Comment: Não. Um *Controller* é um objeto cujo ciclo de vida é muito pequeno, sendo rapidamente descartado após o processamento de suas ações. Então, a segunda forma "não é a única correta".

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez melhorou?

Comment: Não, veja só. O `dispose` do contexto sempre vai acontecer, independente de usar o `using` ou não. É comum *Controllers* terem, sei lá, 10 *Actions*, todas usando o contexto. Cada requisição normalmente chama uma *Action* só (às vezes chamam mais do que uma). Neste caso, o problema da segunda forma é que você tem que declarar o bloco pra todas as *Actions*, que, além de não ser prático, não proporciona ganho algum.

Comment: Eu mudaria para: "As duas formas são corretas, mas na prática do dia-a-dia, a primeira forma é mais usada pelo número de *Actions* em comum que usam o contexto".

Comment: É verdade. Mudei.

Comment: Ok, agora sim. +1.