# O que são as actions de um controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net

[Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93725/18246) o Cigano diz

> Este (exemplo) aqui é bom quando você possui várias Actions no Controller

O que são as *Actions* de um *Controller*?

Obs.: Gostaria de algum exemplo de código também, definindo um *controller* com duas ou mais *actions* e ver como essas *actions* são "chamadas".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No ASP.NET MVC as urls são mapeadas para métodos (Actions) em classes que definem os chamadas controladores (Controllers). As requisições enviadas pelos navegadores são processadas pelos controladores.

O processamento realizado por um controlador para tratar uma requisição consiste basicamente em:

- Recuperar os dados enviados pelo usuário através de formulários
- Interagir com a camada de modelo.
- Acionar a camada de apresentação para construir a página HTML que deve ser enviada para o usuário como resposta à sua requisição.

Para que uma classe seja considerada um controlador, ela deve seguir algumas regras.

- O nome da classe deve ter o sufixo "Controller".
- A classe deve implementar a interface `System.Web.Mvc.IController` ou herdar da classe `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`

Um controlador pode conter diversas ações (Actions). As ações são utilizadas para processar as requisições realizadas pelos navegadores. Para criar uma ação, é necessário definir um método public dentro da classe de um controlador. Os parâmetros desse método podem ser utilizados para receber os dados enviados pelos usuários através de formulários HTML. Esse método deve devolver um **ActionResult** que será utilizado pelo ASP.NET MVC para definir o que deve ser executado depois que a ação terminar.

Por padrão, quando criamos um projeto ASP.NET MVC no Visual Studio, uma rota com o formato **{controller}/{action}/{id}** é adicionada na tabela de rotas. Com essa rota, se uma requisição for realizada para a url http://www.k19.com.br/Editora/Listagem, o controlador definido pela classe
EditoraController e a ação implementada pelo método Listagem() dessa classe serão escolhidos para processar essa requisição.

Exemplo:

```
public class EditoraController
{
  public ActionResult Listagem()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

Fonte: [K32 - Desenvolvimento Web com ASP.NET MVC](http://online.k19.com.br/libraries) Página: 129