# Redirecionar para Action de acordo com if

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho um `Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string pUsuario, string pSenha)
{
     usuario oUsuario = modelOff.usuarios.Where(p => p.usuario1 == pUsuario && p.senha == pSenha).SingleOrDefault();
     if (oUsuario == null)
         return IR_PARA_ACTION_1;
     else
         return IR_PARA_ACTION_2;
}
```

Como fazer para selecionar a `Action` de acordo com o resultado do meu `if`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando [`RedirectToAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx), passando o nome da action como parâmetro.

Dica: o método de extensão `SingleOrDefault` recebe um predicado, você não precisa aplicar um `Where` e depois `SingleOrDefault`. Além disso, o `else` é desnecessário.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string pUsuario, string pSenha)
{
     usuario oUsuario = modelOff.usuarios.SingleOrDefault(p => 
                                           p.usuario1 == pUsuario && p.senha == pSenha);
     // ^^ Dica 1: Usar apenas SingleOrDefault()

     if (oUsuario == null)
         return RedirectToAction("Action1");

     return RedirectToAction("Action2"); // <- Dica 2: Não precisa do else
}
```

Comment: Recebo um erro de que nem todos os caminhos retornam um valor

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo então você não usou o código exatamente como o LINQ postou. O código dele sempre retorna algo.

Comment: O erro está na linha `public ActionResult Login(string pUsuario, string pSenha)` na palavra `Login`

Comment: Faltava o ponto-e-vírgula, @ItaloRodrigo

Comment: O código rodou, porém estou recebendo um erro 404 quando envio o formulário. Estou usando o código assim: `if (oUsuario == null) { return RedirectToAction("Index"); } else { return RedirectToAction("Login"); }`

Comment: Então é porque a action não existe. A "index" é no mesmo controller?

Comment: A `Index` é a que eu inicio nela. Dá o erro quando eu vou pra `Login`. Só uma dúvida: `Action` é o mesmo que `View`?

Comment: Não. Action é o metodo, view é o arquivo cshtml. Seria bom ler isso: [O que são as actions de um controller?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93728/18246)

Comment: Então estou fazendo errado. Minha ideia é retornar uma `View`. Vou ver se consigo adaptar o código aqui. Obrigado.

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo É só criar uma action para esta view.