# Quando é recomendável que uma classe implemente IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, interface, dispose

Utilizo o padrão IOC no meu projeto o qual facilita a chamada de procedimento do tipo `Resolver.Resolve<IPedido>().GerarPedido()`, porém, não queria deixar "solto" desta forma, gostaria de implementar o método `IDisposable` usar assim:

```
using (var pedido = Resolver.Resolve<IPedido>())
{
  pedido.GerarPedido();
}
```

1. Posso implementar `IDisposable` em um classe simples, nesse exemplo, `Pedido`? Seria uma boa prática?
2. Tem custo de processamento?
3. Qual a melhor forma de implementar `IDisposable` nesse exemplo?

Comment: Para uma classe ter de implementar *IDisposable* tem de haver uma razão, neste seu caso qual é?

Comment: Bem, no meu entendimento, queria `matar` `Resolver.Resolve<IPedido>().GerarPedido()` logo após sua execução. A classe `Pedido` é uma classe básica, não utiliza nenhum componente externo.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow O que significa "matar" o pedido?

Comment: Tirar da memória :) @dcastro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A função do bloco `using{}`, usando palavras suas, não é "matar" uma objecto de forma a que ele "não fique solto".
Isso é da responsabilidade do *garbage collector*.

O método `Dispose()`, que faz parte da interface *IDisposable*, é normalmente usado para libertar *resources* alocados pela classe que, se não forem libertados poderiam criar *memory leaks* quando o objecto fosse colectado pelo GC.

A função do `using` é permitir que as classes que implementem IDisposable sejam usadas de forma a garantir a execução do método `Dispose()` no fim da sua utilização, mesmo que seja lançada uma exceção.

Assim, a implementação da interface *IDisposable* só é recomendada quando é necessário efectuar algum procedimento após a utilização do objecto e antes de ele ser colectado pelo GC.

Implementação dessa interface, só por si, não garante que o método `Dispose()` seja chamado, mas indica ao utilizador/consumidor que o deve fazer.

Answer (score 7):

1. Pode implementar, claro. Você pode fazer o que você quiser.
2. Há custo de processamento. Se ele será problema ou não, é preciso avaliar.
3. A melhor forma é não implementar. Afinal não parece que isto use algum recurso externo que a aplicação não tem controle, então não faz sentido implementá-lo.

A não ser que tenha alguma coisa obscura dentro deste pedido não tem razão alguma para implementar esta interface e adotar o padrão de disposição. E se tiver algum motivo provavelmente esta classe está implementada de forma errada. Não posso dar detalhes porque a pergunta não dá detalhes sobre a classe.

O objeto deve ser reclamado pelo *garbage collector* no momento certo e não ficará solto. Se não está acontecendo isto é porque tem problemas. O GC é inteligente, ele sabe bem quando deve fazer. Ele só não é milagroso, se algo estiver impedindo ele coletar tem que resolver este problema.

Leia [mais sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101).

Sobre o [gerenciamento de memória do .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

Comment: Entendi, como o @ramaral `deve-se ter uma razão` para usar IDisposable, no caso do exemplo, o GC dá conta, já que, `Pedido` é uma classe simples e não utiliza nenhum componente externo.