# Múltiplas conexões com banco - Executável c# com multi task

Tags: c#, oracle, multithreading

Tenho um executável que eu preciso rodar uma base de dados **gigante**. Como o tempo de processamento seria inviavel se eu fizesse em uma unica `Thread`.... Seguindo a ideia desta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123173/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-task-e-thread), resolvi criar um executável que faça N tarefas em paralelo... Então basicamente eu faço sempre a mesma coisa para intervalos de tempo diferente.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var dataInicio = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-35);
        var dataFim = DateTime.Now;

        var listaTasks = new List<Task>();

        while (dataInicio > dataFim ? dataInicio >= dataFim : dataInicio <= dataFim)
        {
            var d = dataInicio.Date;
            var meuBll = new MeuBll();
            listaTask.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                                        {
                                           meuBll.Foo(d);
                                        }).ContinueWith(
                                            x => meuBll.Dispose())
                               .ContinueWith(x => GC.Collect()));

            var meuBllNovo = new MeuBll();
            listaTask.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                                        {
                                            meuBllNovo.Boo(d);
                                        }).ContinueWith(
                                            x =>
                                            meuBllNovo.Dispose())
                               .ContinueWith(x => GC.Collect()));

            if (listaTask.Count >= 2 * 5)
            {
                Task.WaitAll(listaTask.ToArray());
                listaTask.Clear();
            }
            dataInicio = dataInicio > dataFim ? dataInicio.AddDays(-1) : dataInicio.AddDays(1);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(listaTask.ToArray());
```

Então basicamente eu escolhi rodar, por exemplo, um intervalo de 10 dias de uma só vez, como vocês podem ver em `if (listaTask.Count >= 2 * 5)`, o problema é que meus métodos `Foo` e `Boo` tem várias conexões com um unico banco de dados oracle...

```
public class MeuBll : IDisposable 
{
    private readonly OracleDal _oracleDal = new OracleDal();

    public void Foo(DateTime data)
    {

        var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
                     {
                         _listaSucesso = _oracleDal.ObterListaSucesso();
                     });

        var t2 =
            Task.Run(() =>
                         {
                             listaFalhas = _oracleDal.ObterListaFalhas();
                         });

        t1.Wait();
        t2.Wait();

        foreach (var sucesso in _listaSucesso)
        {
            //uma logica para inserir objetos em uma "lista de merge"
        }

        if (listaDeMerge.Any())
            Task.Run(() => _oracleDal.MergearLista(listaDeMerge)).Wait();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_hash != null)
            _hash.Clear();
        _hash = null;

    }
}
```

E meu método de merge:

```
    public void MergearLista(List<MyObject> listaMerge)
    {
        using (var conn = new OracleConnection(Connection.ConnectionString))
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();
            using (var oCommand = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                oCommand.CommandText = string.Format(@"
                MERGE INTO MyTable dgn 
                USING (select id from another_table where field = :xpe) d ON ( TO_CHAR(dateHappen, 'DDMMYYYY') = {0} and id = :xId) WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                    UPDATE SET OK = :xOk, dateHappen = SYSDATE
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
                    INSERT (fields....) 
                    VALUES (values...)");
                oCommand.BindByName = true;
                oCommand.ArrayBindCount = listaMerge.Count;



                oCommand.Parameters.Add(":xId", OracleDbType.Int32,
                                        listaMerge.Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.Id)).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);

                oCommand.Parameters.Add(":xPe", OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                                        listaMerge.Select(c => Convert.ToString(c.Xpe)).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);


                oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

O problema é que para cada dia de processamento, o processo leva em torno de 2 horas... e diariamente tem uma rotina para fazer backup no banco, o que faz ele ficar fora por 10 minutos aproximadamente, o que irá fazer meu executável lançar alguma `Exception` ou simplesmente `lockar` alguma tabela..

O que eu faço? Paro o executável "na mão" e ponho para rodar novamente tirando os dias que ele já executou... Além disso, muitas conexões ficam simplesmente abertas... Então eu mato essas sessões na mão também...

Como resolver isso? Tem alguma forma de forçar todas as conexões em aberto a simplesmente fecharem? Forçar o `Dispose` delas?

Comment: Não li sua pergunta ainda mas bati o olho em uma coisa e já te falo pra ler isto antes de mais nada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101

Comment: Vou ler! Mas assim, tava estourando a memória devido à grande quantidade de dados... não vi outra alternativa a não ser forçar o GC assim que eu não precisasse mais dos meus objetos..

Comment: Se está estourando a memória, tem duas saídas, coloca mais memória (nem sempre isto resolve) ou muda o algoritmo. Ainda não sei qual é o problema, mas provavelmente o código como um todo tem que ser repensando. O problema não é a coleta de lixo, é o lixo produzido. Não tente acabar com o sintoma, cure a doença.

Comment: @bigown, sim...estava estourando a memória, daí eu melhorei o algoritmo e aparentemente melhorou... mas assim, já tinha implementado a questão de forçar o GC...e não mexi novamente. O problema está em dar `Dispose` em todas as conexões abertas...

Comment: Sobre o `dispose()`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102609/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98341/101. Eu não entendi a função dele no código. Você tentou fazer este algoritmo sem `Task` primeiro, deixar ele redondinho e depois aplicar `Task`? Quase sempre é o jeito certo a se fazer, a não ser, e olhe lá, se dominar muito o uso de `Task`. Tem vários trechos de código que não fazem o menos sentido. Daí eu concluo que se até em coisas simples está confuso, imagine na parte complicada.

Comment: A utilidade dele é deixar todos os objetos `null` para que o GC force a limpeza deles.... Ele já existe hoje sem `Task`, só que demora demais o processamento.

Comment: Mas é justamente o que **não pode** fazer. Isto por si só já pode ser parte do problema. Se fizer um *profiling* da aplicação provavelmente vai descobrir que o que tá matando ela é o GC trabalhando como louco. Eu tenho bem pouca experiência com código usando `Task`, mas nunca vi um da forma usada. Não estou dizendo que ele está errado, não tenho como afirmar isso, mas ele me parece estranho. No mínimo difícil de entender. Tem coisa que eu não sei nem se está compensando ter as tarefas (só especulando). Você sabe pelo menos onde é o gargalo? Pode ser o DB.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o que existe hoje, tem todos estes problemas. Saneie eles e depois pense em `Task`. Você deve ter lido isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101. Eu acho que o seu caso é de algoritmo errado. `Task` pode até melhorar, mas não vai solucionar nada. Talvez quando achar a solução, `Task` seja desnecessário. Quase todos problemas de performance é de algoritmo e não de falta de concorrência. Comece descobrindo onde está lento de forma detalhada.

Comment: @bigown, o problema definitivamente está no banco... basicamente eu lido com tabelas com mais de 50 milhões de registros, onde muitas vezes é necessário joins (na maioria das vezes por VARCHAR) com outras tabelas gigantes.... é realmente um problema mais que conhecido... precisamos e vamos remodelar o banco.... mas até lá, esse algoritmo até que ajudou...existe um que faz a mesma coisa, só que com uma thread só...e leva 4 horas de processamento...esse com multi thread faz em 2 horas.. o problema maior nele é controlar todas as conexões... acho que não tem jeito de fazer isso :(

Comment: Se fizer direito talvez cai para alguns minutos mesmo com uma só.

Comment: po, big... tu é um cara que manja demais, tenho grande respeito e admiração pelo trabalho que você faz por essa comunidade... Mas eu sou do pensamento que sempre vai ter um jeito melhor de se fazer.... e as vezes precisamos trabalhar com o que se tem, principalmente quando "brigamos" com o tempo... prazos apertados, etc... e tratando-se de uma aplicação grande que simplesmente "caimos" de paraquedas no meio do desenvolvimento, fica complicado de pensar-se em refatoração... (no meu caso, seria refatoração da refatoração)... Basicamente eu preciso varrer a base toda "para ontem". é complicado rs

Comment: Sim, claro, mas muitas vezes o prazo estoura porque fica brigando com coisa errada. Meu TCC na faculdade foi resolver um problema que era lento demais leva cerca de 80 dias para completar. Uma equipe ficou trabalhando por 6 meses e não conseguiu resolver. Eu reduzi para 1 minuto e meio (nos computadores atuais faria em algo em torno de 1 segundo). Estou dizendo isso não pra dizer que sou bom (nem acho isso), até pq o que eu fiz foi simples demais, levei 2 dias, a maior parte para entender o que tinham feito. Quero dizer que muitas vezes resolver o problema dá menos trabalho que contorná-lo.

Comment: Entendi.... mas sei lá, eu não sei....acho que se o banco fosse estruturado de uma outra forma, mais da metade dos problemas estariam resolvidos.... mas como eu falei é complicado... a falta de um DBA dá nisso.... rs