# Para que serve uma implementação explícita de interface em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, interface

Costumo a utilizar interfaces em PHP e consegui fazer um exemplo semelhante, só para testes, em C#.

```
class MyClass : IWriter {
    public string Writer(string str) {
       return str;
    }
}

interface IWriter{
       public string Writer();
}
```

No entanto, fui avisado que essa implementação acima é a chamada de "implícita" e que em alguns casos era recomendável usar a "implementação explícita".

Dei uma olhada no link [Implementação de interface explícita (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173157.aspx), mas isso gerou confusão. Pois eu não consigo visualizar ainda nenhum caso onde eu precisaria usar a "implementação explicita".

É claro que como eu estou acostumado com o PHP pode ser a razão da confusão, mas é a primeira vez que vejo uma implementação explícita de interface numa linguagem.

No exemplo da MSDN, está assim:

```
class Test 
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SampleClass sc = new SampleClass();
        IControl ctrl = (IControl)sc;
        ISurface srfc = (ISurface)sc;

        // The following lines all call the same method.
        sc.Paint();
        ctrl.Paint();
        srfc.Paint();
    }
}


interface IControl
{
    void Paint();
}
interface ISurface
{
    void Paint();
}
class SampleClass : IControl, ISurface
{
    // Both ISurface.Paint and IControl.Paint call this method. 
    public void Paint()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Paint method in SampleClass");
    }
}
```

Qual é a vantagem de usar implementação de interface explícita em relação a implícita?

Quando devo usar a implementação implícita e quando, a explícita?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Na verdade, o recomendado é a implícita mesmo. Há casos que a explícita é necessária. Há controvérsias se isso é algo bom ou não. Há quem diga que nem deveria existir na linguagem porque pode gerar confusão. Eu sou sempre da opinião que se tem algo que pode resolver um problema de forma melhor, deve dar essa opção, mesmo que tenha restrições de uso. Mau uso é um problema que qualquer recurso pode ter.

## Interface implícita X explícita

A implícita é o que todo mundo faz o tempo todo, você implementa na classe um ou mais métodos que uma interface "manda" e que essa classe deseja se conformar. Não tem segredo.

A explícita é a implementação dizendo nominalmente para qual interface essa implementação deve ser usada. É uma forma excepcional de implementação porque haverá alguma situação em que é necessário um comportamento diferente do normal da classe quando se espera a interface.

## Lembrando o que é polimorfismo

No polimorfismo você pode tratar um objeto de um tipo como se fosse de outro tipo. Então se você cria um método que recebe, por exemplo, um `IEnumerable`, qualquer objeto que implemente esta interface, pode ser passado para esse método e tudo o que ele fará é acessar o `GetEnumerator()` (especificado pela interface). Ele não acessará outras partes do objeto, por isso não interessa para ele o resto que tem no objeto. Só interessa que isso esteja presente.

O compilador do C# garante a presença do que interessa. Na maioria dos casos a presença do método na forma chamada implícita é suficiente e tudo funcionará.

## Pra que serve?

Por mais que o ideal seja fazer de um jeito, sempre tem situações onde as coisas não funcionam como se deseja. Além disso há limitação da linguagem em fazer certos padrões que a solução acaba sendo o uso da interface explícita. Aqui vão os principais motivos para usar.

#### Problema do diamante

Existem alguns raros casos onde essa implementação deve ser um pouco diferente. Isso ocorre com mais frequência quando há conflitos de implementações de duas interfaces. Uma deve funcionar de um jeito e a outra deve funcionar de outro jeito. Normalmente você só poderia ter a implementação de uma forma. A explicitude da implementação permite ter uma variação. Uma situação comum ocorre no caso do [problema do diamante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem). A interface ajuda resolver o problema, mas tem casos que pode se tornar um problema maior ter a mesma implementação para mais de uma interface.

Para explicitar usa-se o nome da interface antes do nome do método. Exemplo:

```
public void Paint() { //implícita
    WriteLine("Paint method in SampleClass");
}
void IControl.Paint() { //explícita para a IControl
    WriteLine("IControl.Paint");
}
void ISurface.Paint() { //explícita para a ISurface
    WriteLine("ISurface.Paint");
}
```

Como executa:

```
var sc = new SampleClass();
IControl ctrl = (IControl)sc;
ISurface srfc = (ISurface)sc;

sc.Paint(); //Paint method in SampleClass
ctrl.Paint(); //IControl.Paint
srfc.Paint(); //ISurface.Paint
```

Veja os efeitos de chamar pela classe e por cada uma das interfaces. Note como cada chamada executa um método diferente mesmo sendo, teoricamente, o mesmo método. Está [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/sBbhKR). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mxQQH8). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/InterfaceOverImplementation.cs).

#### Especialização

Outro caso é que a implementação da classe pode ser feita de forma mais eficiente ou fazer algo extra, mas isso pode não conformar com o que é esperado na interface. Então quando for usado em um lugar que se espera a interface, é executado a implementação mais simples e compatível. Quando puder chamar a implementação da classe chama a implementação "melhorada". Essa versão melhorada poderia ferir a expectativa do que a interface deve fazer.

#### Compatibilidade

Pode ser útil em casos de mudança futura na interface, assim ajudará manter a compatibilidade com a versão antiga e nova, afinal a interface agora exige algo que já existia na sua classe. Isso é comum em sistemas mais internos, principalmente quando se adiciona um método com nome já existente mas com uma nova assinatura.

Um exemplo seria uma interface `ICalculo` que tem um método `CalculaSaldo()`, aí cria-se um novo método `CalculaSaldo(TipoCalculo tipo)`. Só que a classe que já conformava com esta interface já tinha se antecipado a esta necessidade e tinha criado um método com esta assinatura, mas a implementação não bate com o que se espera deste método especificado na interface. A solução é criar um novo método de forma explícita para atender a interface.

Ou seja, é gambi, nunca deveria ser feito isso, mas há casos de necessidade e quando acontece pelo menos é uma solução.

#### Encapsulamento

Ela pode ajudar melhorar o encapsulamento, assim você deixa claro que as implementações são diferentes, mesmo que não seja de fato. Fazendo isso, pelo menos quando precisar poderá mudar uma delas sem preocupação com o que acontecerá com o método exposto publicamente. Exemplo:

```
interface IDisposable {
    void Dispose();
}
class MyFile : IDisposable {
    void IDisposable.Dispose() {
        Close();
    }
    public void Close() {
        // fecha o que tem que fechar aqui
        SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
Public static void Main() {
    var file = new MyFile();
    file.Dispose(); //erro não pode chamar aqui
    IDisposable file2 = new MyFile();
    File2.Dispose(); //ok, funciona
}
```

Assim a chamada do método `Dispose()` fica impedido quando se chamada pela classe. O que é uma boa, já que muitos programadores fazem essa chamada por engano, o que não é recomendado e eles não sabem disto.

É uma forma de simular uma implementação privada da interface. Há casos em que a implementação concreta não precisa dos métodos da interface para ele em si. Precisa apenas para atender a demanda da interface, então é melhor esconder isso dos objetos concretos gerados com base nela.

Essa é uma forma de [programar explicitamente para a interface e não para implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86507/101).

A melhor forma é sempre atender o [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), e a implementação explícita pode facilitar ou dificultar isso. Aí depende do caso, nem sempre o que temos na mão pode ser o ideal.

Classes que herdam da sua classe com implementações explícitas não recebem essas implementações. Tão pouco podem tê-las virtuais. Só as implícitas são herdadas. Isso é algo importante para se observar quando se pensa no *design* da hierarquia. Tem casos que se deseja isso e quer manter o nível certo de especialização.

Uma vantagem de usar essa técnica é que se um dia a interface remover um método do seu contrato (raro acontecer), as interfaces explícitas gerarão erro no compilador e obrigará você removê-las do código. Na implementação implícita não gera erro porque ela passa fazer parte da classe. De fato, nesse caso a remoção só poderia ser feita com muito cuidado e aceitação de risco.

## Pode ser ruim

Além de poder gerar confusão no seu uso, nem todo mundo entende o que vai ser chamado e a pessoa pode ter dificuldades até para depurar o código.

Existe um problema prático de perda de performance por ser obrigado fazer *boxing* em tipos por valor, daí recomenda-se evitar interfaces explícitas nesses tipos. Não é possível acessar um tipo por valor pela interface sem fazer o encaixotamento dele em uma referência.

## Conclusão

Como tudo, tem vantagens e desvantagens. Fora a limitação da linguagem, um bom *design* evitaria o uso desse mecanismo. E ele deve ser evitado mesmo

[Artigo do Eric Lippert sobe o assunto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/odious-ambiguous-overloads-part-one?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). [Parte 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/odious-ambiguous-overloads-part-two?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Guideline do Brad Adams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brada/design-guideline-update-explicit-member-implementation?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Answer (score 13):

Isso tem a ver com isolamento de escopo de objeto. No início do exemplo que você mencionou, podemos ver que dois objetos são criados, cada um com uma visão diferente do objeto:

```
IControl ctrl = (IControl)sc;
ISurface srfc = (ISurface)sc;
```

Que se traduz da seguinte maneira:

> Crie uma variável **ctrl**, que me apresente o objeto **sc** como um **IControl**.
>   Crie uma variável **srfc**, que me apresente o objeto **sc** como um **ISurface**.

Entretanto, ao chamar o método `Paint()` de `ctrl` o que você vê não é *específico* da apresentação da interface `IControl`, mas sim o conteúdo genérico gerado pela implementação da classe. O mesmo se aplica à `ISurface`.

Você pode então estar ferindo as espectativas de retorno em outras partes de seu código.

Comment: Como no C# temos a questão de poder ter dois métodos com o mesmo nome, **para mim** faz sentido a implementação explícita. Em linguagens como o PHP, que não aceita métodos com nomes iguais por exemplo, não faria sentido algum.,

Comment: @WallaceMaxters uma coisa não tem nada a ver com a outra. *Overloding*  não tem relação com isto. Inclusive é possível a interface ter mais de um me´todo com o mesmo nome (mas não mesma assinatura). Na verdade é oposto. Em PHP faria até mais sentido. Este mecanismo é para desambiguar a implementação do mesmo método (mesma assinatura). Note que tecnicamente o nome é diferente, já que tem um "sobrenome" nele.