# O que é IEnumerable.GetEnumerator em C#?

Tags: c#, sintaxe, interface

Estava lendo [esta documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=netcore-3.1#examples) e deparei-me com o seguinte trecho de código dentro de uma classe que implementa `IEnumerable`:

```
// Implementation for the GetEnumerator method.
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return (IEnumerator) GetEnumerator();
}
```

Mas o que é exatamente esse `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`? Sei que `IEnumerable` é uma interface, mas aí `GetEnumerator` seria uma propriedade dessa interface?

A dúvida ficou porque geralmente coloca-se o nome do método no lugar onde está `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`. Nesse sentido, vejo o nome de um método como algo *concreto*, então como uma "propriedade de interface" poderia assumir esse papel? Seria algo como um nome especial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetEnumerator()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=net-5.0#examples&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) termina com parênteses, certo? E se tem isso, como em todas linguagens, seria um... método!

O que parece estranho é ter um sobrenome no método. E isso se dá com o que se chama [implementação explícita de interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133957/101). É uma forma especial de dar nome para a implementação conforme mostra detalhes no *link*.

Hoje isso pode ser escrito assim:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/GetEnumerator.cs).

Temos aí o tipo de retorno, o nome do método precedido de qual é a interface que ele está fazendo a implementação, que diferencia da implementação padrão do próprio tipo, e depois o corpo que apenas chama um outro método existente na classe fazendo um *cast* para compatibilizar o retorno deste método.

Se não quebrasse compatibilidade todo sistema de enumeração do C# seria refeito, tem erros na ideia toda, é um dos maiores problemas da linguagem, e que a maioria das pessoas nem percebe.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! :-) Fiquei curioso com os problemas do sistema de enumeração do C#, você tem alguma referência para que eu possa entendê-los melhor?

Comment: Essas coisas você vai vendo com acúmulo de informação, mas não falar que não tem nada, vou dar um exemplo: https://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2014/08/19/rethinking-enumerable.html e https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1931 e https://stackoverflow.com/q/23536541/221800 e https://www.monitis.com/blog/how-c-ienumerable-can-kill-your-sites-performance/ e https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/9paafp/enumerators_avoiding_bad_usage/. Por causa dele há situações que ocorre *boxing* sem o programador perceber e sem precisar porque em geral poderia ser um tipo por valor.

Comment: Por isso até andaram melhorando em um ponto ou outro, exemplo: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/extension-getenumerator. E já tem casos que o compilador faz otimizações. Veja: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/378