# Não consigo criar uma classe iteradora com IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, genéricos, enumerable

Estou criando uma classe iteradora — tem suporte para `foreach` — implementando a interface `IEnumerable<T>` do pacote `System.Collections.Generic`, como no código abaixo:

```
public class MyList<T> : IEnumerable<T> {

    private T[] list;

    // Código...

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        for (int index = 0; index < this.list.Length; i++) {
            yield return this.list[index];
        }
    }
}
```

O problema é que o compilador está gerando o seguinte erro:

```
error CS0738: "MyList<T>" não implementa membro de interface "IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
". "MyList<T>.GetEnumerator()" não pode implementar "IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()" porqu não tem o tipo de retorno correspondente de "IEnumerator".
```

Qual o problema no código? O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Revisei o código diversas vezes e, aparentemente, a implementação está de acordo com a documentação.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760322/troubles-implementing-ienumerablet

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/479755/69296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No stackoverflow em inglês tem uma [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760322/troubles-implementing-ienumerablet) semelhante a sua, segue a tradução livre da resposta aceita

Como `IEnumerable<T>` implementa `IEnumerable` você precisa implementar essa interface também em sua classe, que tem a versão não genérica do método `GetEnumerator`. Para evitar conflitos, você pode implementá-lo explicitamente

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    // chama a versão genérica do método
    return this.GetEnumerator();
}

public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        yield return _array[i];
}
```

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida. Qual a vantagem de usar o IEnumerable genérico? Pesquisando aqui, eu vi que é possível utilizar apenas o `IEnumerable` e o `IEnumerator`. Então, por que a documentação manda usar o genérico?