# Qual o modificador de acesso de uma implementação explícita?

Tags: c#, herança, interface

Criei uma classe iteradora que implementa a interface `IEnumerable<T>`, que implementa a interface `IEnumerable`. Para fazer a implementação corretamente, é necessário implementar explicitamente o método `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`, como no código abaixo:

```
public class MyClasst<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
    private int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
            yield return this.list[i];
        }
    }
```

Note que na implementação do método da interface não genérica, nenhum modificador de acesso é declarado. Sempre que eu coloco qualquer modificador de acesso —  `public`, `internal`, `protected` ou `private` — o compilador gera um erro, informando que não é permitido.

Dito isso, minha dúvida é:

- Qual o modificador de acesso definido pelo compilador para esse tipo de implementação?
- É possível acessar esse método especificamente, seja dentro ou fora da classe? Se sim, como o método deveria ser invocado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A implementação explícita de interface é sempre pública (veja a [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#explicit-interface-member-implementations?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)). Não tem razão para não ser, e decidiram que já que é a única forma, não permitiria dizer no código que é, até porque de certa forma é como se ela fosse privada à interface. É confuso, e eu falo disso no *link* abaixo.

Não é possível acessar a implementação específica pela classe diretamente, só através da interface, mas usando-a pode acessar sem problemas em qualquer lugar.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var x = new MyClasst<int>();
        WriteLine(((IEnumerable)x).GetEnumerator());
        WriteLine(x.GetEnumerator());
    }
}

public class MyClasst<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
    private T[] list;
    
    public IEnumerable Teste() => (IEnumerable)GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        WriteLine("Explícita");
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        yield return this.list[0];
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/e8t6vA). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BgZ2YF). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/ExplicitInterface.cs).

Note que chamar diretamente não chama a implementação explícita.

O código foi escrito apenas para demonstrar o mecanismo, ela não tem funcionalidade prática e não deve ser usado assim. Esse `yield` não parece estar correto (mesmo que funcione), mas não vou afirmar sem ver o todo.

Mais sobre o assunto: [Para que serve uma implementação explícita de interface em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133957/101).