# Método Dispose()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dispose

O `dispose()` libera o objeto da memória, certo? Eu não sei quando é necessário usá-lo. Por exemplo, eu tenho uma página, nesta página há um `listBox` com 
`visible = "false"`, em um evento este `listBox` passa a ser `true`.

Em um outro evento a `div` que contém este `listBox` é escondida: `display: none`. A `listBox` que foi preenchida anteriormente continua ocupando a memória, não é? Só não aparece na tela pois a `div` foi escondida. No momento em que eu escondo a `div` seria recomendável dar um `dispose()` no `listBox` já que o mesmo não está sendo usado (apresentado na tela)? O `listBox` só aparecerá novamente se o usuário clicar no botão que dispara o evento para preenchê-lo novamente.

Comment: Na primeira implementação do método de clique do botão gravar deveríamos ter utilizado o método Dispose() da conexão. Com o uso da instrução using isto não se faz mais necessário. Pesquise sobre a finalidade do método Dispose() e por que a instrução using dispensa o uso do mesmo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> O `Dispose()` libera o objeto da memória, certo?

Não. Só o coletor de lixo faz isso. O que ele faz é liberar recursos não gerenciados, externos à aplicação. Eventualmente eles podem ocupar alguma memória não gerenciada, mas isso não é problema seu, você libera o recurso.

> A `listBox` que foi preenchida anteriormente continua ocupando a memória, não é?

Sim.

> No momento em que eu escondo a `div` seria recomendável dar um `dispose()` no `listBox` já que o mesmo não está sendo usado (apresentado na tela)?

Não. Porque este não é um recurso "dispensável" (veja documentação dele e a interface `IDisposable` não é implementada). Não poderia nem que quisesse.

Mesmo que fosse o caso, o fato de você apenas esconder o elemento não tem teria porque dispensá-lo.

Mas na verdade o problema é outro. Você está falando de um recurso do C#/.NET para aplicar em algo que efetivamente só rodará no cliente (o navegador). O C# não tem qualquer ingerência no que rodará lá. Mesmo que fosse possível dar um `Dispose()` nesse objeto, não afetaria o *listbox* em si porque ele não é um elemento da aplicação C# e sim da página HTML/JS. A classe do ASP.ET só é responsável por gerar o texto HTML/JS e gerenciar os estados que receberá dele, ela não é o *listbox* mesmo.

- [Devo sempre utilizar Dispose()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101)
- [Quais tipos de recursos são liberados em uma declaração "using"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101)
- [Quando é recomendável que uma classe implemente IDisposable?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98341/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).