# Como ver os processos abertos dentro do Visual Studio?

Tags: c#

É possível saber quais são os processos abertos dentro do Visual Studio através de alguma tecla de atalho? Eu estou debugando e a mensagem de erro é que o arquivo esta aberto em outro processo, verifiquei se era a conexão do banco de dados, se era outra pessoa e até mesmo fechei e abri novamente o VS.

```
string sb = @arquivo.Caminho + "\\" + repositorioArquivo.AtribuiData(arquivo.Nome_fisico, dataReferenciaArquivo);
StreamReader arqLido = new StreamReader(@sb); //da exceção aqui
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito provavelmente isto não tem a ver com o Visual Studio. Este arquivo você está tentando abrir pelo seu código, certo? Se sim, perceba que isso é um problema no código e **não tem relação com o Visual Studio**. Se for o caso, você precisa [edit] a pergunta e mostrar o código que usa para abrir este arquivo.

Comment: @LINQ Descobri onde estava dando problema, passava por um método que simplesmente só lia o arquivo

Comment: Ótimo, você precisa sempre fechar todo e qualquer _stream_ que abrir. Usando `Dispose()`.

Comment: Bom, marquei a pergunta como duplicata porque se trata do mesmo problema.

Comment: Relacioado: [Porque usar o bloco using no ASP.NET MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93717/18246)