# Liberar memória de objetos

Tags: c#, .net, memória, interface, dispose

De que maneira posso liberar memória de objetos além da classe `IDisposable`?

```
foreach (var conta in listItensContas)
{
 ItemPedidoImp itensPedidoToImp = new ItemPedidoImp()
  {
   Quantidade = conta.Quantidade,
   Descricao = conta.Descricao,
   ValorTotal = conta.ValorTotal,
   Data = conta.Pedido.DataPedido
  };
 itensImp.Add(itensPedidoToImp);  

}
```

Nesse trecho de código é criado um objeto para cada item. Na criação de um novo objeto, o anterior é sobrescrito, ou um novo é alocado na memória?

Comment: Título referente a uma dúvida e no contexto outra dúvida. Todo new é uma nova instância então a sua lista os objetos criados são únicos não repete não sobreescre.  A interface IDisposable é uma outra história implementação dela é simples mas existe o momento correto de fazer isso deve ser estudado e no site da Microsoft explica como deve ser feito.

Comment: Site https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8 fácil de entender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe uma classe `IDisposable`. Existe uma interface que serve para adotar um padrão de projeto de projeto chamado Disposable ou Descartável. Você precisa implementar esse padrão de forma adequada, o que não é fácil, na sua classe para que ela faça o descarte de recursos não gerenciados. Se não fizer a liberação manual dentro deste padrão nenhuma liberação ocorrerá, este padrão apenas automatiza a chamada da liberação que foi feita. Se não sabe fazer isto não crie uma classe que precise disso, portanto evite abstrações que exijam isso. É difícil e poucas pessoas sabem fazer certo.

Note que falei de recursos não gerenciados. Memória gerenciada não tem que fazer nada, o *garbage collector* fará tudo por você se não tiver alguma maluquice no código que impeça isso, mas é até difícil alguém criar um código que gere um problema assim.

Se está tendo problemas de memória o problema pode ser outro bem diferente de onde parece, ele aparece quando tudo já está entupido e não onde começa o entupimento.

Toda vez que dá um `new` está criando um novo objeto (é feita uma alocação), então não está passando por cima de nada. E na lista também não está pondo por cima porque sempre adicionando um novo elemento e não usando um já existente. Se deseja que algum seja descartado, e não vejo porque desejaria isso neste caso, mas pode ser só porque não sei o contexto todo, então teria que fazer uma lógica que reaproveita o objeto em vez de criar um novo.

Comment: Sou um desses que não sabe como implementar esse padrão, quando preciso liberar memória, eu faço a classe herdar a interface _IDisposable_, implemento um método     
`public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }`
Fui ensinado a fazer assim , mas não sei como isso funciona. Onde posso encontrar mais informações sobre como implementar corretamente?

Comment: Isto não está liberando nada e pode até estar evitando alguma liberação. Se ensinaram fazer assim, ensinaram errado. Na documentação tem mais material, mas tem que prestar bastante atenção. Em geral as pessoas não erram porque ensinaram errado, é que eles não prestam atenção em todos detalhes e começam fazer coisas diferentes do que foi ensinado. Aqui mesmo se pesquisar sobre tá cheio de pergunta sobre o assunto. Esse caso mesmo eu duvido que faça sentido fazer isto, mas só posso afirmar vendo tudo.

Comment: Muito interessante, vou ler e reler a documentação até conseguir entender, pois onde trabalho é dessa forma que eles "liberam memória", no fim não resolvia nada, foi de grande ajuda essa informação a performance do sistema vai melhorar muito com isso.