# Memory leak no XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, gerenciamento-de-memória, garbage-collector

Tenho o código abaixo. Como o método é `static` e o `XmlSerializer` não implementa o `Dispose`, a cada chamada do método, o sistema empilha na memória ou o `GC` (*garbage collector*) consegue limpar esta variável?

E no caso de classes que não tem `Dispose`, para destruir a variável posso fazer `converter = null`, ou tenho que fazer algo a mais? Pois no meu entendimento, o `null`, só limpa o valor, mas deixa a variável no ponteiro da aplicação.

```
public static string ConverterObjetoEmTexto(object dados)
{
    var retorno = "";
    XmlSerializer converter = new XmlSerializer(dados.GetType());

    using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        converter.Serialize(textWriter, dados);
        retorno = textWriter.ToString().Replace("encoding=\"utf-16\"", "encoding=\"utf-8\"");                           
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `XmlSerializer` não precisa de `Dispose()` porque ele não aloca recursos. Ele apenas aloca memória, então quando encerrar a execução do método, o objeto não terá referência para ele. Ele poderá ser removido da memória a qualquer momento pelo GC.

Isto não quer dizer que ocorrerá na hora, pode demorar, mas o GC é inteligente o suficiente para saber a hora certa de remover da memória, não vai lhe causar problemas.

As variáveis locais só existem durante a execução do método onde estão contidas. Se o seu conteúdo não for escapado para fora do método, o objeto apontado pela variável fica órfão e poderá ser eliminado a qualquer momento.

Isto difere do `StringWriter` que tem recursos não gerenciados alocados e precisa ter uma padrão para informar que aquilo pode ser eliminado. Por isso você precisou usar o [`using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41175/101).

Este código está correto e não vai vazar memória.

Comment: se por acaso acontecer que o XmlSerializer isto dentro de um try / catch, ele não iria gerar vazamento de memória?

Comment: Não, saiu do método, não importa como, a variável será destruída e o objeto ficará órfão, podendo ser coletado a qualquer momento. A variável fica no *stack* (neste caso). O objeto fica no *heap*. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101

Answer (score 2):

Existem basicamente 2 regras onde a implementação do IDisposable é necessária:

1. O objeto mantém recursos não gerenciados;
2. O objeto mantém recursos gerenciados que implementam IDisposable;

O XmlSerializer não cai em nenhuma dessas regras.

O IDisposable é geralmente implementado em conjunto com o ~finalizer() de forma com que caso o dispose() não seja chamado, isso será feito quando o objeto for destruído.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms244737.aspx

PS: Uma implementação mais eficiente do seu ConverterObjetoEmTexto segue abaixo:

```
    public static string ConverterObjetoEmTexto(object dados)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var textWriter = new EncodedStringWriter(sb, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            new XmlSerializer(dados.GetType()).Serialize(textWriter, dados);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Você vai precisar dessa classe:

```
    public class EncodedStringWriter : StringWriter
    {
        private readonly Encoding encoding;

        public EncodedStringWriter(StringBuilder stringBuilder, Encoding encoding) : base(stringBuilder)
        {
            this.encoding = encoding;
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get
            {
                return encoding;
            }
        }
    }
```