# Como funciona a relação do "using" e do garbage collector do .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, memória, garbage-collector, using

Em uma resposta agora apagada aqui no site parece que houve alguma confusão com o conteúdo indicando o uso do `GC.Collect()` e como o `using` do C# trabalha. Então como de fato funciona o `using` e qual a relação que ele tem com o GC do .NET?

O `using` realmente libera recursos do sistema operacional?

O que são estes tais recursos? É memória?

É o GC que libera esses recursos?

Quando de fato esses recursos são liberados, no fim do bloco do `using` ou quando o GC for invocado? Faz diferença invocar manualmente ou deixar ele ser invocado? Tem um conceito de fazer a liberação assim que possível.

Por que o `using` existe se o `GC` é que cuida disto?

O que acontece se não usar o `using` corretamente?

Se usá-lo corretamente tem como o recurso não ser liberado? Ou seja, pode ser que o recurso seja liberado só depois?

Em discussão lá foi afirmado que no trabalho do autor teve recursos que não foram liberados imediatamente. Quando isto acontece? É possível a liberação não ser imediata em alguma situação?

Toda memória é liberada quando libera o recurso?

Lá foi afirmado que o GC liberará os recursos porque ele já foi avisado que o objeto não está mais em uso. Mas o GC (pelo menos o *tracing*) não existe justamente para determinar se o objeto está em uso ou não e não precisar ser avisado? Isto está confuso.

O `using` de fato dá algum aviso ou se comunica com o GC para indicar que ele deve liberar esses recursos?

Não há nada no `Dispose()` que se comunica com o GC?

Documentação está sempre certa?

E por fim, devo chamar `GC.Collect()` manualmente? Quando? O que acontece de ruim se eu chamar? Por que o método existe se não deveria chamá-lo?

Quanto mais detalhes melhor, pra ficar claro mesmo.

Comment: O motivo de eu postar isto é que houve muita discussão sobre o assunto logo após eu ter dado *feedback* (depois tem gente que reclama que não recebe quando toma negativo), e eu precisava explicar com detalhes todos os erros encontrados ali. Eu sugeri que fosse feita uma nova pergunta para entender melhor o erro mas sabia que isto não aconteceria por causa da atitude de considerar que não havia erro.

Comment: Sabia que viria negativos, sempre terá alguém que aproveita. Eu prefiro receber negativos, ao contrário do que alguns acham eu não me preocupo com reputação mas sim com respostas corretas e tenho orgulho delas e de todas minhas conquistas. Não acho justo com as outras pessoas terem uma resposta errada e nada ser falado. Postei também porque me aconselharam não ficar discutindo, "põe um *llink* que mostra o erro e boa". Note que não é o caso de discutir, de diferença de interpretação, havia um erro claro lá e tento ajudar as pessoas saberem como funciona de verdade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pergunta é melhor entendida com o contexto da resposta apagada e a discussão que aconteceu lá.

> Em uma resposta agora apagada aqui no site parece que houve alguma confusão com o
> conteúdo indicando o uso do `GC.Collect()` e como o `using` do C#
> trabalha. Então como de fato funciona o `using` e qual a relação que
> ele tem com o GC do .NET?

Em essência nenhuma relação, a não ser o fato que o `using` foi criado para evitar que o GC precise ser chamado. Notou a oposição?

O GC do .NET é *tracing* e por isso ele não é determinístico, ou seja, você não sabe quando ele será executado, a não ser que chame manualmente, mas não deve chamá-lo (ver abaixo). Alguns tipos de recursos (falarei depois) precisam ser liberados de forma determinística e por isso precisa de um mecanismo que faça isto no código sem precisar invocar o GC de forma alguma.

O `using` libera recursos, o GC libera memória, isto será melhor esclarecido logo.

> O `using` realmente libera recursos do sistema operacional?

Sim, em alguns casos. De fato é comum que esses recursos sejam providos pelo sistema operacional, mas existem várias outras formas de obter e ter que liberar esses recursos que não são do sistema operacional, pode ser de qualquer serviço externo, por exemplo banco de dados, muito comum.

Pode ter até objetos que não acessam diretamente recursos externos. Se ele acessar indiretamente é provável que precise ter esse mesmo padrão *disposable pattern* que o `using` usa, é viral.

É muito comum vermos aqui no site pessoas criando classes para gerenciar conexão, e como a conexão precisa ser descartada (chamar o [`Dispose()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), provavelmente com o `using`) o objeto que detém essa conexão precisa ser *disposable* também (precisa implementar corretamente a interface [`IDisposable`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98341/101)), mas muitas não o fazem. Vemos isso direto, provavelmente as pessoas viram errado em algum lugar e aprenderem assim. Este é um dos motivos que vaza tanto recurso por aí.

Ainda que seja comum que esses recursos sejam advindos do sistema operacional existem vários casos que não são, não pode-se afirmar que são só do SO.

> O que são estes tais recursos? É memória?

Recurso é algo que a sua aplicação não consegue gerenciar, não é memória gerenciada, portanto não é memória que o *garbage collector* cuida, é exatamente o oposto, se este recurso tiver alguma alocação de memória ela é gerenciada por si própria, o recurso é que cuida disto, e libera quando o recurso achar melhor, é problema dele, o GC jamais interferirá nisto, ele nem tem noção dessa memória (não é tão simples assim, mas nã ovamos complicar).

Uma das coisas que muitos não entendem é que essa liberação pode envolver nada de memória, gerenciada ou não. Poderia ser apagar uma lâmpada e mais nada, essa liberação é finalizar algo, é determinar que está encerrando aquilo, que não operará mais ali.

Isto já foi respondido com mais detalhes em [Quais tipos de recursos são liberados em uma declaração "using"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101).

Veja também: [Memory leak no XmlSerializer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94910/101).

E ainda: [Método Dispose()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173210/101).

Pode haver confusão aí quando o autor fala que não liberou recurso, ele pode estar falando que não liberou o objeto que controlava o recurso e acha que o recurso ainda está lá disponível (pode ser até perigoso tentar acessar um recurso por um objeto que está zumbizando)

> É o GC que libera esses recursos?

Não, nunca. Essa liberação só ocorre por invocação do seu código, ainda que em alguns casos de forma implícita. A forma implícita mais comum é através do `using`. O `using` chamará o método `Dispose()` e este chamará o que for necessário para liberar o recurso. É muito comum que o método a ser chamado seja um `Close()` ou algo parecido. E este `Close()` chame a API do sistema operacional, banco de dados ou outro serviço que proveu o recurso. A liberação de verdade é problema do recurso, você chama uma função da API que diz que você não precisa mais disto, só isto, a API dispara o resto que ele precisa fazer.

Nós falamos de liberar recursos porque na maioria dos casos quando chama essa função realmente começa o processo de liberação, mas não há garantias que isto ocorra na hora. Então pode estar pensando que ele será liberado depois e você deve se preocupar, certo? Não, não é sua preocupação, sua aplicação não precisa fazer mais nada, o recurso se vira, ele vai liberar se ele foi bem feito, e o que as pessoas realmente usam foram bem feitos, só dará um problema se for algo feito por uma pessoa ingênua e sem capacidade de fazer aquilo.

Por favor, não entenda errado, a liberação ocorre na hora em quase todos os casos, e se tiver algum que não acontece não faz diferença para sua aplicação, para todos os efeitos para sua aplicação foi liberado. O .NET não quer saber disto em nenhum momento mais. Estou falando assim para ser absolutamente correto, até pedante, mas de forma simplificada podemos dizer que o recurso é sempre liberado na hora.

> Quando de fato esses recursos são liberados, no fim do bloco do
> `using` ou quando o GC for invocado? Faz diferença invocar manualmente
> ou deixar ele ser invocado? Tem um conceito de fazer a liberação assim
> que possível.

No fim do bloco do `using` sempre! (por falar nisto em C# 8 nem precisa mais do bloco é possível declarar a variável com um atributo `using` e a liberação ocorrerá no fim do bloco atual, não precisa criar um bloco só para o `using`. Não mudou nada na semântica, só na sintaxe. Assim:

```
void Metodo() {
    using var http = new HttpClient();
    http.......
    ...
} // o recurso da variável http será liberado aqui
```

O `using` na verdade é transformado em algo assim:

```
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    try {
       // Algum código...
    } finally {
        if (http != null)
            ((IDisposable)http).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Uma coisa curiosa é que justo o `HttpClient` costuma fazer uma espécie de *pool*, então essa liberação é só dizer que um membro do *pool* passa ficar disponível, mas nem para o sistema operacional há liberação alguma, a não ser que o algoritmo interno achar que deve liberar. Por isso tem que tomar cuidado porque a terminologia usada costuma ser uma simplificação do que realmente acontece.

Na verdade [todo mundo usa `HttpClient` errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422717/101), eu mesmo já usei e não sabia de tudo, porque eu confiei que a documentação tinha tudo o que eu precisava, mas aprendi a lição.

Como curiosidade de como é o `Dispose()` desta classe:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && !_disposed)
    {
        _disposed = true;

        if (_disposeHandler)
        {
            _handler.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

A classe `HTTPClient` não tem destrutor, portanto "o recurso" dela não será reclamado se você não usar certo, mas vou mostrar de outra classe:

```
~FileStream()
{
    // Preserved for compatibility since FileStream has defined a
    // finalizer in past releases and derived classes may depend
    // on Dispose(false) call.
    Dispose(false);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/Using.cs).

> Por que o `using` existe se o `GC` é que cuida disto?

Justamente porque ele não cuida da mesma coisa. Este é um dos erros da resposta lá.

O `using` cuida do recurso, algo externo, algo que o .NET não tem controle, algo que precisa encerrar de forma determinística e... imediata. O GC cuida da memória do .NET, da sua aplicação, ele cuida do objeto que será criado para acessar o recurso, mas é diferente do recurso em si. É um objeto que faz um *wrap* no recurso, é ele que tem métodos e alguns campos para controlar o acesso ao recurso. O recurso é outro objeto separado na memória não gerenciada pelo GC e que todo .NET não entende como lidar com ele.

> O que acontece se não usar o `using` corretamente?

O recurso não é liberado na hora de forma determinística. Isto não é o fim do mundo em alguns casos, mas pode criar problemas para a aplicação. Já vi muito caso de lentidão, consumo excessivo de memória e até de bloqueio de acesso ao recurso que deveria ter sido terminado mas ainda está ativo em algum ponto.

Aqui entra o GC. Quando o GC faz a coleta de objetos não mais utilizados pela aplicação ele chama um método `~Classe()` (todo objeto tem este método porque ele é um [destrutor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9078/101) (chama também `Finalize()` mas não vou detalhar pra não confundir mais). Em muitos casos ele não faz nada, mas onde tem um `Dispose()` ele tem quase uma obrigação de chamar o `Dispose()` por isso se o `using` não for usado corretamente ainda em algum momento pode ser que o recurso seja liberado, e este momento é quando o objeto que controla o recurso pode ser liberado pelo GC. É uma questão de dependência, se o objeto já não é mais usado e o GC está autorizado a destruí-lo ele precisa garantir que qualquer coisa anexada a ele seja liberado junto, caso contrário esse recurso ficaria pendurado e vazaria.

Pode-se dizer que toda a vez que um `Dispose()` é executado através do destrutor e não do `using` tem algo errado no seu código e precisa de conserto. Tá cheio de código assim por aí.

Usar o `using` corretamente não resolve todos tipos de vazamento.

Eu falo muito do `using` mas é claro que o `Dispose()` pode ser chamado de forma determinística manualmente no seu código, só não deve fazer isto porque provavelmente fará de forma errada, tem um jeito certo de fazer, o padrão de projeto do `using` está aí para você não errar sem querer, só precisa usá-lo no lugar certo. Tem bastante conteúdo no site sobre isto.

> Se usá-lo corretamente tem como o recurso não ser liberado? Ou seja,
> pode ser que o recurso seja liberado só depois?

Nesta condição jamais ocorre isto. Se o recurso acabar sendo liberado depois é porque o `using` está errado, provavelmente nem existe onde deveria.

> Em discussão lá foi afirmado que no trabalho do autor teve recursos
> que não foram liberados imediatamente. Quando isto acontece? É
> possível a liberação não ser imediata em alguma situação?

Lamento que o código que ele trabalha esteja com esses problemas. Tem dois caminhos, começar estudar mais o assunto e consertar o problema ou conviver pra sempre com o erro, ou até aparecer alguém lá e consertar. Eu já fui chamado para consultoria justamente pra resolver isto já que este tipo de coisa é o que mais gosto e tenho experiência.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Só o erro provoca a liberação do recurso posteriormente. A liberação é tão imediata que pode levar pouco mais que 1 ou 2 nanossegundos para iniciar a liberação (em boa parte dos casos levará alguns ns, mas se começar levar mais que isto tem algo errado). Pra concluir pode levar mais tempo, até us ou ms, mas isto é raro e sempre deve suspeitar se tem algo errado. E lembrando que o .NET não precisa necessariamente esperar a conclusão.

> Toda memória é liberada quando libera o recurso?

Não, de maneira alguma. A memória do objeto que contém o recurso nunca é liberada na hora que libera o recurso, são coisas distintas. A liberação da memória do objeto *container* do recurso, que geralmente é bem pequena comparada com o recurso, mas isso varia um pouco, só é liberada/destruída quando o GC determinar, e isto só acontece quando ele pode provar que em nenhum outro lugar da aplicação ele pode ser acessado mais.

O objeto em si fica vivo ainda mesmo que ele não esteja sendo usado, pelo menos até a próxima execução do GC (xiii, a coisa tá piorando, porque nem é garantido que em toda execução do GC o objeto seja destruído, fica mais não determinístico ainda, para garantir que um recurso seja liberado pelo GC pode ser necessário chamar o `GC.Collect()` várias vezes e nem podemos saber quantas são necessárias, pode ser milhões em um caso extremo, a não ser que já mande fazer uma coleta completa, que é bem lenta, ou seja, faça isto e destrua a performance da sua aplicação).

Isto não quer dizer nada sobre o recurso que já foi liberado.

> Lá foi afirmado que o GC liberará os recursos porque ele já foi
> avisado que o objeto não está mais em uso. Mas o GC (pelo menos o
> *tracing*) não existe justamente para determinar se o objeto está em uso ou não e não precisar ser avisado? Isto está confuso.

Não há aviso algum do `using`, o `Dispose()` ou qualquer coisa parecida com o GC para liberar algo depois ou qualquer coisa do tipo.

Mas pode haver um aviso sim, porém é justamente para fazer o contrário, é um aviso **para não liberar** o recurso, porque o `Dispose()` já o fez.

Lembra que eu falei que o GC poderia [finalizar o objeto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e liberar o recurso de forma emergencial se o código tivesse falhado em fazer isto na hora certa? Pois bem, se tudo foi feito certo o GC não deve fazer isto, o destrutor não deve ser chamado, e este é o único aviso que o `Dispose()` faz ao GC.

Não é bem que ele avisa o GC, ele marca o objeto para o GC depois saber que não deve finalizar.

Obviamente que isto só ocorre se o `Dispose()` é escrito de forma correta, não acontece magicamente.

> O `using` de fato dá algum aviso ou se comunica com o GC para indicar
> que ele deve liberar esses recursos?

Para liberar o recurso não, para avisar que já foi liberado pode ser interpretado que tem um aviso, ainda que não seja bem isto que ocorre.

> Não há nada no `Dispose()` que se comunica com o GC?

Sim, o método [`GC.SuppressFinalize()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.suppressfinalize?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) faz isto conforme dito acima. Veja [mais sobre ele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102609/101).

> Documentação está sempre certa?

Não, este é um mito que muitos acreditam. Mas o maior problema é como as pessoas interpretam a documentação, e o motivo que muita gente faz algo funcionar mas não está certo (veja a foto acima). As pessoas acreditam no que elas veem funcionando, quando elas deveriam acreditar no que está escrito na documentação.

Sabe o que você deve fazer com o que não está escrito? Considerar que aquilo não existe. Sabe por que? Por que não existe mesmo! Se não tiver uma garantia escrita na documentação de algo considere que aquilo não é garantido, mesmo que você saiba que pode fazer aquilo.

Eu nem estou falando de documentação errada ou incompleta. E isso tem muito, inclusive da Microsoft. Este ano eu tive uma conversa com boa parte do time do .NET, C#, VS, etc. em Redmond à convite da Microsoft, em especial com o [Jared Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar) e o [Immo Landwerth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847438/immo-landwerth) falamos sobre as falhas do documentação que ferraram eles que cuidam do C# e .NET.

Fotos (já que minha credibilidade foi questionada): [Jared Parsons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuBtH.jpg) [Immo Landwerth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58bM9.jpg)

Lá a gente até brincou sobre o uso do famoso `Thread.Sleep()` que as pessoas encontram em exemplos da documentação e não sabem porque a aplicação fica lenta, e se surpreendem quando tira isto e fica rápido. Conclusão, as pessoas não sabem nem usar documentação, elas acham que lá tem tudo o que precisam saber sobre o assunto e é só copiar os exemplos que estão lá que tudo ficará bem. Tadinhos.

O mais importante é que a documentação de um método fala só o mais importante sobre ele, não diz toda repercussão que ele terá, principalmente se isto for detalhe de implementação porque esse tipo de detalhe pode mudar e exatamente por isso não pode ser documentado. Mas se sabe como a implementação atual funciona :)

> E por fim, devo chamar `GC.Collect()` manualmente? Quando? O que
> acontece de ruim se eu chamar? Por que o método existe se não deveria chamá-lo?

Não deve chamá-lo manualmente, nunca! Ou quase, falo disto em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101). Esse nunca é relativo, claro que para testes específicos ou depuração pode ser útil. Em caso de emergência porque você achou um problema sério no gerenciamento de memória, pode por para rodar por um período muito curto para minimizar um problema, mesmo que cause outros, mas que permita o uso da aplicação.

Se você chamar manualmente faz os objetos jovens que morrem logo e tem a coleta de forma muito barata passar paras as gerações seguintes de forma prematura, mantendo o objeto em área mais difícil de coletar dando um trabalho muito pior para o GC, e em alguns casos inviabilizando a aplicação, que é o que pode acontecer de melhor para você (porque aí terá que resolver o problema em vez de se lamentar que não está bom).

Entenda mais sobre as [gerações do GC do .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/200713/101).

O método existe justamente para diagnóstico, para experimentar, ou salvação extraordinária, não para por em produção em quase todos casos. Tem algum tipo de estrutura que ele pode ser útil, mas quase nenhum programador usa isto, é complexo demais e quem sabe lidar com isto sabe lidar com o GC, você provavelmente nem sabe do que estou falando de tão raro que se usa isto.

[Tem isso na documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/induced?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), sim, tem lá, não na documentação do método, mas tem. [Tem no blog do Rico Mariani](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/two-things-to-avoid-for-better-memory-usage?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ([mais uma página dele falando no assunto e que ele é bem claro para não usar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/when-to-call-gc-collect?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)), um dos maiores especialistas no .NET (recomendo todo seu blog para quem quer entender sobre .NET - ele era funcionário na época envolvido na criação e evolução principal do .NET e o GC é um dos assuntos que ele mais trabalhou, é bom avisar aqui porque algumas pessoas não leem e acham que não importa, sim teve quem desdenhou desses *links* como se eles não fossem confiáveis, por exemplo de onde tinha resposta do [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) que não é nada, só o criador do compilador do C# e das melhores respostas de todo o SOen, além de cuidar de Hack no Facebook), e tem diversas respostas no SOen, bem votadas, dadas por várias pessoas, algumas bem reputadas em todos os sentidos (não só de pontos no SO). E tem aqui também, mas como a maioria foi postada por mim e minha credibilidade foi contestada (sem argumentação ou alguma base para falar disto, sem ser alguém que tem algum histórico que indique que conhece o assunto) não considere tão importante minhas respostas.

- [When is it acceptable to call GC.Collect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/478167/221800) (esse [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) não deve entender nada desse .NET, e o [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick) que andou por lá mesmo sem responder é outro que não deve entender nada do assunto pra confirmar o que está escrito)
- [Best Practice for Forcing Garbage Collection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/233596/221800)
- [Usage of GC.Collect Method in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6572883/221800)
- [How to force garbage collector to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4257372/221800)
- [When to use GC.Collect() in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5383535/221800) (tadinho do [Reed Copsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65358/reed-copsey), não entende nada)
- [What's so wrong about using GC.Collect()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/118633/221800)
- [Should i call GC.Collect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15206119/221800)
- [is it smart to use GC.Collect on application that runs 24h per day?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8972758/221800)
- [Forcing GC.Collect() to reduce chances of running during time sensitive code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15711627/221800)
- [When is it a good idea to force garbage collection?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/276585/when-is-it-a-good-idea-to-force-garbage-collection)
- [Em quais momentos se faz necessário forçar a coleta de lixo em C# para um melhor desempenho da aplicação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101)
- [Impacto do Garbage Collector](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153878/101)
- [Como identificar e evitar memory leak no .NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186644/101)

A pessoa que questionou disse que não importa todos esses *links* de todas essas pessoas qualificadas, o que ela acha que é que importa, e eu é que fui chamado de arrogante. Eu posso falar besteira sobre assuntos que eu não entendo bem, tem respostas minhas que são questionáveis, nem tudo o que eu posto é 100% certo, mas este assunto eu tenho orgulho do que falo, eu posso falar algo que alguém não entenda até por ser um assunto que não é fácil para a maioria, mas não é comum eu errar nisto. Posso até não saber algo deste assunto, mas é difícil eu saber errado. Pode dizer que isto foi pretensioso, mas precisava ser dito, não acho que sofro de [Dunning-Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) nisto, sei até das limitações que tenho no assunto.

Chamar `GC.Collect()` depois do `using` "para liberar o recurso logo" é gambiarra da grossa e oposta ao propósito, é errado!

Preferi nem entrar no detalhe que as pessoas que chamam este método não chamam o [`GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que pode agravar ainda mais as coisas, porque quem chama o `GC.Collect()` já está fazendo algo errado, melhor que cause bastante problema, ou seja, é um recurso avançado que depende de muito conhecimento e faz xixi na mão de criança. Não passe perto disto se não dominar o GC.

Isto é necessário porque a coleta é assíncrona e nada garante que ela terminou. Então até a afirmação que este método liberará o recurso imediatamente está errada se pegar a ideia de forma estrita. Relutei pra escrever isto porque pode gerar confusão pra muita gente. O recurso pode demorar um pouco, mas pro .NET já foi liberado imediatamente.

Pare quem quiser se aprofundar tem [documentação do GC e o código fonte](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/garbage-collection.md) dele onde mostra tudo isso e porque chamar este método é prejudicial.

#Conclusão

O assunto é até mais complicado que isso, o GC tem muitas nuances e a forma de criar a finalização e disposição é bem complicada, e quase todos os programadores devem ficar longe disto. Tem uns "criadores de bibliotecas" por aí que não sabem como criar esse tip ode objeto e faz bastante estrago por aí, já vi aplicação sofrendo e a culpa era da biblioteca que a pessoa usava, aí não tem `using` correto que dê jeito.

Mais sobre *garbage collector*:

- [O que é Garbage Collector e como ele funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255769/101)
- [Garbage collector é automático?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204344/101)
- [O Garbage Collector remove todos objetos ou somente os que não tem referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/344564/101)
- [Por que chamar o System.gc não garante execução do garbage collector?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105092/101)
- [O coletor de lixo existe mesmo? Por que então há vazamento de memória em runtimes que utilizam-no?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/308679/101)

Comment: Como previsto os negativos vieram sem *feedback*.

Comment: Como felizmente eu ainda não perdi a curiosidade me diga em quê *"todo mundo usa HttpClient errado"*?

Comment: Não pode ficar criando e matando ele como a gente vê em código por aí, como eu já fiz uma vez (não aqui), só cria um por aplicação, e por isso ele costuma nem ser descartado (curiosamente tem uma ligação com o que falamos no outro comentário porque é um caso que você não costuma usar o `using` com ele :) ). Tem mais detalhes, mas em comentário é basicamente isso. Eu lembrei disso escrevendo a resposta, como não costumo usá-lo tinha até esquecido o que eu descobri quando fui ver a documentação :D Você pode não errar, mas quase todo código que vejo erra, vide exemplo lá da outra pergunta.

Comment: Fazer parte da equipe de desenvolvimento do .NET deve ser uma conclusão de vida excitante.

Comment: É claro que sempre algo pode escapar-me, mas estou ciente que tenho de garantir que o Dispose() é sempre chamado antes que o objecto, que o usa, esteja disponível para o GC.

Comment: @ramaral em regra geral, sim, mas não garanto que isso seja uma obrigatoriedade em todos os casos. Claro, se puder ser diferente é caso extraordinário, não é o normal. Só estou falando que não tenho informação não que não exista algo obrigando isto que citou, mas também consigo ver cenário (posso estar enganado) que dispor o recurso mas não o objeto tenha alguma utilidade. Mesmo que faça diferente terá um risco.

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor como funciona o 'using' e 'dispose' nas injeções de dependências? Ou recomendar alguma leitura pra tentar entender melhor essa parte?

Comment: Você teria que fazer uma pergunta porque é muita coisa pra comentário, fora ser outro assunto, provavelmente mostrando um exemplo. Capricha que não é fácil fazer bem essa pergunta :)