# Aplicação em Xamarin causando lentidão após algum tempo

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms, paralelismo

Estou criando uma aplicação em Xamarin Forms, entretanto estou tendo alguns problemas de lentidão. Nessa aplicação, eu utilizo muito processamento paralelo, e o aplicativo funciona bem até certo ponto, mas quanto mais ele é usado, mais ele vai ficando lento (ele abre e fecha continuamente, é um dos eventos do USB). O Aplicativo precisa permanecer aberto de forma indefinida, ou seja depois de um 9 horas ele já começa a apresentar problemas.

Eu faço uma conexão com o USB do Android, e transfiro informações de forma contínua. Para fazer essa transferência, eu utilizo uma Task recursiva. Foi uma das maneiras que encontrei para fazer a transferência de dados serial, sem que deixasse o aplicativo lento.

Eu uso o `using` sempre que posso e sempre estou dando `Dispose` em algum elemento quando é possível. Depois de algumas modificações o aplicativo está mais rápido, mas tenho medo que essa situação permaneça acontecendo depois de um tempo.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte. Eu devo liberar os recursos de uma tarefa assíncrona? Dei uma olhada por cima, e tudo que encontrei é que não é necessário liberar os recursos da Tarefa, que o próprio Garbage Collector faz esse funcionamento.

Em uma explicação bem legal do Maniero, o que é dito que não devo utilizar o `GC.Collect()` se não souber muito bem como ele funciona, e eu sinceramente não conheço tão bem a ferramenta.

[Garbage Collector](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422625/como-funciona-a-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-using-e-do-garbage-collector-do-net)

Considerando isso tudo, eu limpo as listas que eu percorro nas tarefas que eu crio, e o funcionamento do aplicativo melhorou cerca de uns 100%, provavelmente se eu der um Dispose na Tarefa, seguindo essa mesma hipótese, deve aumentar a performance também. Não me preocupei em esvaziar as listas/objetos que eu tinha nessas tarefas, justamente porque era para ser usado e ao finalizar seria limpo o que aparentemente não está acontecendo.

Como vocês me aconselhariam a seguir em relação a isso? Segue uma parte do código, que eu identifiquei que causa a lentidão.

```
 public async void SendCommands()
    {
        Config.Started = true; // Verifica se a Tarefa começou
        List<Command> NCommands = new List<Command>(); // Cria uma Lista dos comandos que serão enviados para a porta serial
        List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(folder + "/Commands/").ToList(); 
        if (files.Count > 0)
            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    /*
                     Lê o arquivo e deserializa o JSON. Verifica se o arquivo está em uso, se não estiver prossegue e deleta o arquivo.
                     */
                    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(f);
                    Command C = OnDeserializeC(f);
                    NCommands.Add(C);
                    while (IsFileLocked(file))
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(1);
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        if (file.Exists == true)
                            file.Delete();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
         
                        Log.Info("SBI>", ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.Error("SBI", e.Message);
                }
            }

        if (NCommands.Count > 0)
        {
            /*
             Ordena os comandos a serem enviados.
             */
            NCommands.OrderBy(c => c.commandPriority);
            foreach (Command C in NCommands.ToList())
            {
                if (Config.USB)
                {
                    if (SendCommand(C))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            NCommands.Remove(C);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.Info("SBI", "Comandos não enviados");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Info("SBI", "Comandos não enviados");
                }
                await Task.Delay(525);

            }
        }

        await Task.Delay(200);
        Config.Started = false; // Se a Tarefa finalizou, pode iniciar uma nova Tarefa. Faço dessa maneira, pois 
        //toda vez que o programa inicia, ele inicia essa mesma tarefa, isso impede que uma Tarefa seja criada mais de uma vez
        if (Config.USB && !Config.Started)
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendCommands());
        NCommands.Clear(); //Apago os itens da lista, antes de adicionar //essa parte, o aplicativo estava ficando lento ao passar do tempo.
        files.Clear();
```

Valeu!

Comment: Lá não está dito que não deve usar o GC se não entender bem sobre ele, até porque está usando o GC sempre (inclusive no Android o GC é até outro), não deve usar o `GC.Collect()`. Mas precisa identificar a lentidão, pode não ter nada a ver com memória, na forma atual não tem como responder a pergunta, o único jeito é pegarmos sua aplicação e testarmos para achar o problema.

Comment: Adicionei a parte do código que causa a lentidão no aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo. Além disso, deixei mais claro a parte do Garbage Collector que citei, pois eu estava utilizando o GC.Collect com o WaitFinalizers, mas depois que li aquela parte lá, provavelmente irei remover.

Agradeço pela resposta rápida!