# Obter index de caractere com base no Width

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho o seguinte método para calcular a largura de um texto:

```
public float GetWidthOfString(string str, Font font, int bitmapWidth, int bitmapHeight)
{
        Bitmap objBitmap = default(Bitmap);
        Graphics objGraphics = default(Graphics);

        objBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight);
        objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBitmap);

        SizeF stringSize = objGraphics.MeasureString(str, font);

        objBitmap.Dispose();
        objGraphics.Dispose();
        return stringSize.Width;
}
```

Para usar o método, basta:

```
var font = new Font("Arial", 50, FontStyle.Bold);
var texto = "Stackoverflow em Português";

var textoWidth = GetWidthOfString(texto, font, imageWidth, imageHeight);
```

Imagine que `imageWidth = 644`, mas o resultado em `textoWidth` seja maior que `644`. Então irei precisar saber a partir de qual caractere comessa a ultrapassar `imageWidth`.

Comment: Primeiro, chamar o `Dispose()` na mão não é uma boa ideia. Segundo, esta declaração de variáveis do método é muito estranha. Posso estar enganado, mas eu duvido que seja possível determinar isto sem um algoritmo extremamente complexo. Seria mais fácil se fosse garantido que a fonte fosse mono-espaçada.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas @bigown. Sou dev júnior ainda, e gostaria de saber qual o problema em chamar o `Dispose()` na mão? Existe uma alternativa melhor? O que seria uma fonte mono-espaçada e como poderia garantir que minha string seja uma?

Comment: O problema de usar o `Dipose()` na mão é a falta de garantia de que ele será chamado. A alternativa melhor é usar o bloco `using` que nada mais é que um `try-finally` que chama `Dispose`. Uma fonte `mono-espaçada é uma fonte onde todos os caracteres ocupam exatamente o mesmo espaço`.

Comment: Se houver uma exceção, ele não será chamado. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41175/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101. Se não for suficiente, faça uma pergunta sobre isto. A fonte mono tem todos os caracteres com a mesma largura. Aí fica fácil calcular o tamanho de cada um. Deve ter uma informação dentro da fonte que indique que ela é mono. Eu precisaria pesquisar. Mas não sei se você quer garantir isto, limita bastante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que não exista nada pronto pra isso.

A minha dica é: Tire uma letra do texto enquanto o texto for maior que a imagem.

Ex.:

```
while(texto.Length > imagem.Width)
{
    texto = texto.Remove(texto.Length - 1);
}
```

Sobre as tuas pergunta no comentário

> Muito obrigado pelas dicas @Maniero. Sou dev júnior ainda, e gostaria de saber qual o problema em chamar o Dispose() na mão? Existe uma alternativa melhor? O que seria uma fonte mono-espaçada e como poderia garantir que minha string seja uma?

1. O problema de chamar `Dispose()` na mão é que você não tem garantia que de ele será executado. Isso porque no meio do percurso (entre a declaração da variável e o `Dispose()`) é possível que alguma exceção seja lançada e isso fará com o `Dipose()` não seja executado.
2. Sim, existe uma alternativa melhor. Você pode "circundar" a sua variável num bloco `using`, fazendo com que o `Dispose()` seja chamado automaticamente após o uso da mesma. Ex.:

   ```
   using(var objBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight))
   {
       // Ao final desse bloco, o Dispose será chamado
   }
   ```

   Só para fins de curiosidade, este bloco faz exatamente a mesma coisa que

   ```
   var objBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight);
   try{
       // Fazer alguma coisa
   }finally{
       objBitmap.Dispose(); 
   }
   ```
3. **Fontes mono-espaçadas** são fontes onde todos os caracteres têm exatamente a mesma largura, isso faz com que seja fácil calcular qual o espaço que determinada palavra, frase ou texto irá ocupar.