# Fechando requisições

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, exceção, ssl

Atualmente efetuo varias requisições HTTP/HTTPS para sites distintos utilizando as classes `HttpWebRequest` e `HttpWebResponse` utilizando *framework* .NET 4.0*. Estamos enfrentando um problema de quando chega um momento não conseguimos adquirir conexão SSL/TLS , como se chegasse a um gargalo. Gostaria de saber dos senhores se quando uma requisição , feita conforme abaixo, acarreta error (entrando num `catch`) e prosseguindo para  outra assim sucessivamente, se essa requisição é fechada ou não.

```
  PostData &= "&" & System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("btnOK", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) & "=" & System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("OK", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

        url = "www.google.com.br"
        req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
        req.Method = "POST"
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "pt-BR")
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie)
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Pragma, "no-cache")
        req.Referer = "www.google.com.br"
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        req.ContentLength = PostData.Length

    End If

End If

Try

    Dim swRequestWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream())

    swRequestWriter.Write(PostData)
    swRequestWriter.Close()

    Dim srResponseReader As New StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default)

    Html = srResponseReader.ReadToEnd()

    swRequestWriter.Close()

    srResponseReader.Close()


Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
End Try
```

Comment: Eu vi que você nunca votou em nada. Você sabia que além de aceitar uma resposta em pergunta sua, você também pode votar nas perguntas e respostas de todo o site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dessa forma não é fechada não. Se ocorre um erro o comando de fechamento nunca é executado, deixa o recurso aberto e mais cedo ou mais tarde vai causar sérios problemas. O correto é usar o [comando `Using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66230/101) para garantir que o fechamento de recursos que implementam o [padrão Disposable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41175/101) sempre ocorra ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101)).

Nunca chame o `Close()` ou o `Dispose()` por conta própria (a não ser que precise e saiba muito bem o que está fazendo). Isto provoca vazamento de recursos quando há erros.

De qualquer forma provavelmente deveria consertar os erros. Um dos motivos que não está consertando é que está cometendo outro erro. Está capturando a exceção para fazer NADA. Se não tem algo útil para fazer ali não capture a exceção deixe ela propagar para outro lugar onde pode ser feito algo útil. E se ainda não tiver nada útil para fazer deixe a aplicação quebrar. E conserte o erro. Grande parte das exceções são erros de programação que devem ser consertados e não capturados.

E antes que diga que está fazendo alguma coisa quando captura uma exceção, `throw ex;` não é algo útil, ele só destruiu a pilha de chamadas. Se fosse o caso, deveria apenas fazer `throw;`, mas ainda seria um erro ter só esta linha. Este comando só é útil vindo depois de fazer algo útil. Sozinho ele é um erro. Tire este "tratamento" de exceção e leia sobre o assunto na *tag* [exceção](/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o). Leia mesmo, tudo, é necessário aprender usar isto direito. Se tiver dúvidas específicas, pergunte, mas não fique usando a funcionalidade de forma errada.

Esconder a exceção não faz o código funcionar direito.

[Documentação do `Using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Você deverá usar pelo menos 3 deles, talvez mais.