# Uma exception pode ocasionar o fechamento de uma SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, ado.net

Eu estou construindo o tratamento de uma conexão e me veio esta dúvida em mente, mesmo assim, não consegui achar uma resposta satisfatória. Então vim até aqui perguntar aos programadores mais experientes.

Existe alguma possibilidade de quando uma *exception* for lançada uma `SqlConnection` já aberta ser fechada por causa desta *exception*?

Código ilustrativo:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            //algum código aqui....
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //possibilidade de fechamento da conexão? .....
            throw;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ainda que o ideal não seja capturar `Exception` por ser muito genérica e lançar a exceção de novo, não é a coisa mais adequada a se fazer, sim, **é possível colocar o fechamento da conexão ali**. Só que provavelmente não é o que deseja. Você quer que a conexão seja fechada sempre, certo? Se tudo der certo ou se der uma exceção, a conexão deve ser fechado ao final do processo. A linguagem tem um padrão que garante isto de forma muito mais simples e eficaz:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    con.Open();
    //algum código aqui....
}
```

Pronto, você está garantindo o fechamento, não precisa mais nada. O `using` produzirá um `try-finally` chamando o `dispose()` que será responsável por fechar a conexão. O ideal é não tentar fazer na mão, esta é a forma correta e sem riscos.

A conexão poderá ficar pendurada se não fizer isso. Isso vale para qualquer recurso externo que é adquirido. Toda vez que "abre" alguma coisa precisa garantir que será fechado o fechamento não é automático. Esse padrão ajuda alcançar esse objetivo do jeito certo.

- Veja mais em [outra pergunta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99172/101).
- [Mais detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101).
- [Um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101537/101) de caso que o `using` deve ser substituído pelo `try-finally` (veja a alternativa na resposta).

Em C# 9 pode ser:

```
using var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();
//algum código aqui....
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/CloseConnection.cs).

Comment: Na verdade, o que eu gostaria de saber é se quando ocorre uma exception, a conexão pode ou não ser fechada por causa desse erro da exception.

Comment: E está respondido isto.

Answer (score 2):

Você está criando a variável dentro do `try` por isso ela não é visivel fora dele, vou colocar como seria para usar a variável fora porque isso vale para qualquer variável, não só para o caso de conexão:

```
SqlConnection con
 try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            con.Open();

            //algum código aqui....
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            con.Close()
            throw;
        }
```

Existem outras formas de se utilizar isso, até formas melhores para tratar, o mais indicado seria alguma coisa assim: ([código abaixo retirado o desse link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection))

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //
        // Open the SqlConnection.
        //
        con.Open();
        //
        // The following code uses an SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection.
        //
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Dogs1", con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
            reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2));
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Desculpe, me expressei errado, o que eu gostaria de saber é se é possível que quando uma exception é lançada, essa conexão que já esta aberta, seja fechada por causa da exception.

Comment: Você tem que fechar. No primeiro código você mesmo fecha, mas é bom usar o `.dipose()` tb, no segundo código você trata como quiser que ao sair do `using(){}` ele irá fechar, fazer dispose e tudo mais que tiver que ser feito, esse é um dos motivos de se usar sempre `using`