# Como converter um DataSet para Int32?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, webforms, ado.net

Eu estou com um problema de conversão de uma informação que está vindo do meu banco de dados para uma variável do tipo `Int32`.

Quando eu faço o `select max(cur_id) from tbl_curriculo;` eu mando a informação do id direto para um `Dataset` que eu chamo de `ds`.

Eu mando a minha persistência retornar esse `ds` e transformar em `int` para que eu possa mandar esse `id` para outra tabela que receberá esse `id` como chave estrangeira, porém eu não sei como fazer a conversão corretamente.

Quando eu passo o comando `Convert.toInt32()` a IDE acusa que está tudo ok, porém na hora que eu mando rodar o código eu recebo o seguinte erro

> Invalid Cast Exception was unhandled by user code
>   An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Data.DataSet' no tipo 'System.IConvertible'.

Eu seu que a conversão não está funcionando dessa maneira, e também já tentei passar o *dataset* sem fazer a conversão para ver se funcionava e também não funcionou.

Abaixo segue meu código da página onde está sendo feita a conversão

```
protected void btn_Confirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurriculoDB.InsertCurriculo(Persistencia.Cu[0]);

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(CurriculoDB.SelectCur_Id());

        CandidatoDB.InsertCandidato(Persistencia.Cand[0], Persistencia.En[0], id);

        Persistencia.Cand.Clear();
        Persistencia.Curf.Clear();
        Persistencia.Cur.Clear();
        Persistencia.Expt.Clear();
        Persistencia.Contato.Clear();

        Response.Redirect("ConfirmacaoCandidato.aspx");
    }
```

Abaixo o código do `select`

```
public static DataSet SelectCur_Id()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        IDbConnection objConnection;
        IDbCommand objCommand;
        IDataAdapter objDataAdapter;
        objConnection = Mapped.Connection();
        objCommand = Mapped.Command("select max(cur_id) from tbl_curriculo", objConnection);
        objDataAdapter = Mapped.Adapter(objCommand);

        objDataAdapter.Fill(ds); // O objeto DataAdapter vai preencher o 
        //  DataSet com os dados do BD, O método Fill é o responsável por   preencher o DataSet
        objConnection.Close();
        objCommand.Dispose();
        objConnection.Dispose();
        return ds;        
    }
```

Abaixo o código da tabela onde será feito o `insert`

```
public static int InsertCandidato(Candidato can, Endereco end, int id)
    {
        int retorno = 0;
        try
        {
            IDbConnection conexao;
            IDbCommand comando;
            string sql = "insert into tbl_candidato values(0, ?can_nome, ?can_data_nascimento, ?can_sexo, ?can_cpf, ?can_cep, ?can_rua, ?can_bairro, ?can_cidade, ?can_estado, ?can_numero, ?can_complemento, ?fk_tbl_candidato_cur_id);";
            conexao = Mapped.Connection();
            comando = Mapped.Command(sql, conexao);
            comando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?can_nome", can.Nome_candidato));
            comando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?can_data_nascimento", can.Data_nascimento));
            comando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?can_sexo", can.Sexo));
            comando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?can_cpf", can.Cpf));
            comando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?can_cep", end.Cep));
            comando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?can_rua", end.Rua));
            comando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?can_bairro", end.Bairro));
            comando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?can_cidade", end.Cidade));
            comando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?can_estado", end.Estado));
            comando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?can_numero", end.Numero));
            comando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?can_complemento", end.Complemento));
            comando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?fk_tbl_candidato_cur_id", id));
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conexao.Close();
            comando.Dispose();
            conexao.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            retorno = -2;
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou começar com três observações que não vão direto ao problema (poderia falar até de outras coisas).

Eu não entendo porque as pessoas ficam abrindo e fechando conexões o tempo todo dentro da aplicação. Isso é desnecessário na maioria das vezes e ótimo pra criar confusão. A quantidade de código repetitivo aí é impressionante e isso deve se espalhar por toda aplicação. Recomendo o entendimento do [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Claro que pra não fazer isso tem que pensar em uma arquitetura apropriada, mas fica a dica.

Deve-se evitar chamar `Close()` e `Dispose()` manualmente. Se houver uma exceção, fica tudo aberto. É melhor usar o `using`. Referências: [É correto usar um bloco using dentro de outro bloco using?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101535/101), [Método para executar ao destruir instância de uma classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41175/101), [Fechando requisições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99172/101), [Uma exception pode ocasionar o fechamento de uma SqlConnection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106998/101).

Capturar `Exception` não costuma ser legal, ainda mais para fazer o que está sendo feito nesse código. Eu [falo bastante sobre o uso errado de exceções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A101%20%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D), mas já notei que é raro alguém querer aprender fazer o certo.

## Seu principal problema

Pra que criar um *dataset* se a única informação que precisa é o `id`? Não seria mais simples fazer algo assim?

```
var valorParaRetornar = (int)Mapped.Command("select max(cur_id) from tbl_curriculo", objConnection).ExecuteScalar();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/Escalar.cs).

Estou considerando que este `Mapped`, que não sei o que é, faz o que deveria. Obviamente o retorno deste método já será um `int` e não precisará de nenhuma conversão. Este método provavelmente poderia ter 2 ou 3 linhas. Na verdade 1 até é suficiente se estiver bem arquitetado (eliminar abertura de conexão em todo lugar).

É possível pegar o `id` já na inserção se executar junto um `select last_insert_id();`. Ou ainda pegar a propriedade `LastInsertedId` do comando do MySQL para o .NET.

Comment: Muito Obrigado bigown, agora vou direto a raiz do meu problema. Meu professor está ensinando todos a fazer dessa forma que eu estou usando no meu sistema. Eu não sabia que havia uma maneira otimizada de chamar esses dados  durante a minha pesquisa não encontrei essa forma em lugar nenhum. Eu acho muito difícil encontrar material para aprimorar os meu conhecimento em .net e C#, se você está tão antenado assim, de certo conhece algum curso que preste. Se quiser compartilhar o link fico grato.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosAraújo é difícil achar material de qualidade mesmo, a maioria ensina de forma errada. Aqui é um site que a maioria preza pela qualidade e as respostas podem ser confirmas por outras pessoas, então é um bom lugar para pelo menos perguntar quando tiver dúvidas. Se souber inglês o [SO] é melhor ainda. Não costumo indicar nada porque nada gosto de nada existente por aí.

Comment: Sabe, @bigown, já andei dando uma olhada nos seus posts por aí e sinceramente, eu gostaria muito de fazer um curso ministrado por você. Se um dia você resolver dar aula me avisa que eu estarei muito interessado em ser seu aluno.

Comment: No momento não tenho tempo e interesse, uma coisa que gostaria de fazer é escrever um livro, mas falta tempo também, quem sabe um dia. Se todo mundo tivesse a fim de aprender programar de verdade eu até me animaria ir pra esse lado, mas a maioria só quer seguir receita de bolo. Este tipo de coisa eu não gosto de fazer e acho enganação. E também eu sou sincero demais pro gosto de algumas pessoas :D Agradeço os elogios, eu me esforço, mas tenho minhas limitações.

Answer (score 2):

Faça um Cast.

```
int id = (int) CurriculoDB.SelectCur_Id();
```

O cast só deve ser usado se você tem certeza que o resultado da chamada vai ser correspondente ao objeto ou valor.
Ou seja você tem que ter certeza que a chamada:

```
CurriculoDB.SelectCurt_Id();
```

vai retornar um int. Caso retorne um Long ou outro tipo de este long sofrera perda de conteudo. Exemplo:

```
long id = 1000000000000000;
int idComValorPerdido = (int) id;
Console.WriteLine(idComValorPerdido); // 1000000000
```

Repare que ouve perda

Comment: Ele não usou um *cast* e isto não resolve o problema dele.

Comment: Mais informações:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx