# NullReferenceException ao chamar função

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, ado.net, nullpointerexception

Estou criando alguns testes unitário para uma biblioteca de classes que faz manipulações em uma base de dados.

O método que está sendo testado é esse:

```
public object ExecuteNoQueryOperation ( string spOrSqlInstructions, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null )
{
    NpgsqlCommand npgsqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(spOrSqlInstructions, Connection);
    npgsqlCommand.CommandType = commandType;

    if ( parameters != null )
        foreach ( var item in parameters )
            npgsqlCommand.Parameters.Add ( new NpgsqlParameter ( item.Key, item.Value ) );

    try
    {
        Connection.Open ( );

        return npgsqlCommand.ExecuteScalar ( );

    }
    catch ( NpgsqlException e )
    {
        throw new Exception ( "Error: " + e.ToString() );
    }
    finally
    {
        if ( Connection != null && Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed )
            Connection.Close ( );

        npgsqlCommand.Dispose ( );
    }
}
```

E aqui o meu caso de teste:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCallFunction ( )
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dic= new Dictionary<string, object> ();

    dic.Add ( "f_name", "Joice Silva" );
    dic.Add ( "f_age", 31 );

    pgDal.ExecuteNoQueryOperation ( "insertPerson", parameters: dic);

    Assert.AreEqual ( 31, ret);
}
```

Ao rodar esse teste estou recebendo o erro:

> Nome de Teste:    TestCallFunction FullName de
>   Teste:    DataAccessLayerTest.PostgreSqlDataAccessTest.TestCallFunction
>   Fonte de Teste:   C:\Users\Matheus
>   Saraiva\OneDrive\Desenvolvimento\Sistemas\DataAccessLayer\DataAccessLayer\DataAccessLayerTest\PostgreSqlDataAccessTest.cs:
>   linha 39 Resultado de Teste:  com Falha Duração do
>   Teste:    0:00:00,1025821
>
> StackTrace do Resultado:  em
>   DataAccessLayerTest.PostgreSqlDataAccessTest.TestCallFunction() na
>   C:\Users\Matheus
>   Saraiva\OneDrive\Desenvolvimento\Sistemas\DataAccessLayer\DataAccessLayer\DataAccessLayerTest\PostgreSqlDataAccessTest.cs:linha
>   45 Mensagem de Resultado:  Método de teste
>   DataAccessLayerTest.PostgreSqlDataAccessTest.TestCallFunction gerou
>   exceção:  System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não
>   definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Não estou conseguindo identificar o erro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se isso é um teste "formal" você não pode acessar o que bem entende. Na verdade em um teste deve fazer o mínimo necessário. Muitas vezes é só a linha do `Assert` mesmo.

Esse teste não parece fazer sentido. Começando pelo nome. Não informa nada o que está testando.

Se não for um teste, o que não parece, o problema está em outro lugar da classe que não foi postado.

Independente do problema o erro ocorre porque a variável não foi inicializada, no caso a `pgDAL`. A única diferença é que no teste não tem porque ela existir ali, a linha não faz sentido, um teste não pode depender de coisas externas, e se fosse um método normal é só corrigir o erro na inicialização da variável. Não tenho como informar o jeito exato sem maior contexto.

De qualquer o código do método principal está muito complicado. Seria algo mais assim (não sei se é bem isto, não testei e não sei bem o contexto):

```
public object ExecuteNoQueryOperation(string spOrSqlInstructions, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null) {
    using var npgsqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(spOrSqlInstructions, Connection);
    npgsqlCommand.CommandType = commandType;
    if (parameters != null) {
        foreach (var item in parameters) npgsqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(item.Key, item.Value));
    }
    try { //eu deixei isso, mas não é uma boa ideia
        Connection.Open(); //precisa ter uma forma melhor de controlar abertura
        return npgsqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    } finally {
        if (Connection != null && Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/NullParameter.cs).

Não capture exceção para não fazer nada útil. Prefira usar o `using` para dispor recursos. Aproveitei para deixar mais fácil de ler.

Algumas perguntas para ajudar entender o assunto:

- [Minhas respostas sobre exceção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:101%20[exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o]).
- [Fechando requisições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99172/101)
- [Devo sempre utilizar Dispose?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101)
- [Preciso usar o try/catch em toda a cadeia de um processo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128763/101)
- [É correto usar um bloco using dentro de outro bloco using?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101535/101)