# Como saber se um System.Timers.Timer está executando?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

Preciso saber se um *timer* está rodando, caso não esteja, irei iniciá-lo,

Comment: public void iniciarTemporizador()
        {

            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Interval = 10000,
                AutoReset = true
            };

            timer.Elapsed += (sender, z) => OnTeste("", "");
            timer.Start();


        }

Comment: quando chamar esse metodo,preciso saber se timer se encontra iniciado.

Comment: se eu chamar ele mais de uma vez , irei iniciar o timer 2 vezes, preciso iniciar ele somente uma vez.

Comment: A resposta postada resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução apresentada foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que ela é satisfatória. Também pode votar em toda e qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos). Aceitar e votar são coisas distintas.

Answer (score 2):

A classe [`Timer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) não tem nada que controle isto. Se quiser impedir que um *timer* específico seja criado novamente precisa criar um controle próprio com uma *flag* indicando que ele foi iniciado e não deixar iniciar de novo.

Na verdade o problema parece outro. Esse *timer* pode ser destruído quando o *runtime* quiser. Ele está sendo declarado localmente no método, quando o método acaba, o objeto fica livre para ser destruído pelo *garbage collector* **em algum momento**, portanto fazer desta forma é um erro.

Se a intenção fosse que ele deva ser destruído então precisaria garantir que isto ocorresse imediatamente com um [`using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41175/101), não acho que seja o caso.

Se a intenção é manter o *timer* vivo após o método terminar, e parece ser isso, ele deveria ser colocado em uma variável de instância da classe para durar toda existência do formulário, ou até mesmo em uma variável estática da classe se o objetivo for manter vivo em toda aplicação. Se for criado dentro da classe então tem que tomar o cuidado de destruir o *timer* quando o objeto que o contém for destruído (a classe precisará ser *disposable* e ela terá que ser criada adequadamente para isto.

Precisa até pensar se esse é o mecanismo adequado para o que deseja, já vi muita utilização errada dele. Se for, precisa entender todas implicações do seu uso.