# Devo usar um "try-catch" para identificar se uma senha está errada?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, exceção, try-catch

Na tela de *login*, realizo a verificação no banco por meio de um `select`, e estou utilizando o `catch` para capturar essa exceção.

É correto utilizar o `catch` para esse tipo?

```
if (Usuario != string.Empty && Password != string.Empty)
        {
            try
            {
                consql._sql = @"SELECT id_usu FROM login WHERE usuario = @usuario AND password = @password";
                //consql._sql = @"SELECT COUNT(id_usu) FROM login WHERE usuario = @usuario AND password = @password";
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Usuario;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password;
                sqlconn.Open();
                int count_id = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();

                if (count_id > 0)
                {
                    Sessaosistema.UsuarioId = count_id;
                    Sessaosistema.NomeUsuario = Usuario;

                    MessageBox.Show("Usuario logado com sucesso", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    Menu_Inicial mi = new Menu_Inicial();
                    mi.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Usuário ou Senha incorretos" + "\n" + "Revise os dados inseridos e tente novamente", "Falha de Logon", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlconn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Se tiver um problema de alocação de memória, o usuário, e consequentemente você, receberá uma mensagem dizendo "Usuário ou Senha incorretos". Acha que isso está certo?

Se o banco de dados parar de funcionar irá informar que a senha está errada. É o que deseja?

Se tiver os vários outros tipos de exceções em todo o código - que diga-se de passagem faz coisas demais e mistura responsabilidades - **inclusive erros de programação**, quer que o usuário seja notificado que a senha dele está errada?

[Capturar `Exception` quase sempre é um erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101).

Na verdade, pelo que entendi do código, a exceção nada tem a ver com erro de usuário e senha, o que determina se a senha está errada é a condição `count_id > 0`, ou seja, se isso for falso a senha está errada. O uso da exceção não faz o menor sentido. Quase sempre não faz, especialmente para controlar fluxo normal do código, onde o `if` é mais adequado.

É melhor tirar essa exceção, talvez uma mais específica em outro lugar faça algum sentido. E [usar um `using` em `sqlconn`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41175/101) parece melhor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Amigo obrigado pela explicação. vou ajustar meu código.

Comment: Boa pergunta e ótima resposta. E, só para salientar o que muitos programadores fazem: `Try / Catch` não é `If / Else`

Answer (score 4):

O `Try/Catch` mais usado para pegar algum erro de `exception` no sistema tipo problema de conversão essas coisas.

Minha sugestão é que você verifique o count da busca no banco de dados. Se ele retornar 0, é que não existe usuário. Assim você exibe a mensagem  "Usuário ou Senha incorretos",
e deixando o `try` e `catch` para bug de sintaxe mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que vi no seu código, acho que seria legal você utilizar o `try/catch` com a intenção de capturar a exceção caso a conexão com o banco de dados não seja estabelecida, assim você pode apresentar uma mensagem na tela para o usuário informando o mesmo.

Comment: Diego, exato, apos conversar com o pessoal refiz o codigo o catch para pegar esse tipo de exeção.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos ao entendimento das Exceptions e do Try Catch!

Em primeiro lugar, respondendo a sua pergunta, sim acho que podes e deve usar o try catch para capturar o erro de senha, porém com uma questão, antes deves criar uma Exception correta para isto:

```
public class LoginPassInvalidException : Exception
{
    public LoginPassInvalidException() : base("Login ou Senha Inválidos!")
    {
    }

    public LoginPassInvalidException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }

    public LoginPassInvalidException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }

    protected LoginPassInvalidException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
    }
}
```

Após isto fazer o tratamento da exception correta no caso: `LoginPassInvalidException` !!!

Para ter um funcionamento mas aprimorado use desta forma:

```
        try
        {
            consql._sql = @"SELECT id_usu FROM login WHERE usuario = @usuario AND password = @password";
            //consql._sql = @"SELECT COUNT(id_usu) FROM login WHERE usuario = @usuario AND password = @password";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Usuario;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password;
            sqlconn.Open();
            int count_id = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();

            if (count_id > 0)
            {
                Sessaosistema.UsuarioId = count_id;
                Sessaosistema.NomeUsuario = Usuario;

                MessageBox.Show("Usuario logado com sucesso", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                Menu_Inicial mi = new Menu_Inicial();
                mi.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new LoginPassInvalidException();
            }
        }
        catch (LoginPassInvalidException ex)
        {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + "Revise os dados inseridos e tente novamente", "Falha de Logon", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Prezado usuário ocorreu uma ação não prevista, informe ao administrador do sistema: " + ex.Message, "Ação não prevista", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
```

Resumindo, os programadores geralmente não usam as Exceptions como um recurso que pode ser programado, mas o correto é criar as Exceptions para cada erro do seu sistema e tratá-las, bem como as do próprio framework!