# Como disparar múltiplas exceções?

Tags: c#, exceção

```
foreach (Foo el in arr) {
    // ...
    Validate(el);
    // ...
}
```

No código de exemplo, quando o `foreach` é executado, uma exceção pode ser disparada da função `Validate` que será tratada em quem chamou o método que contém o loop.

As exceções disparadas pelo `Validate` tem que ser tratadas pelo usuário. O mais conveniente seria o usuário saber todas os erros que foram jogados para que corrigisse-os antes de reexecutar a função que contem o loop.
Para isso, eu teria que fazer algo do tipo:

```
List<Exception> errors = new List<Exception>();

foreach (Foo el in arr) {
    // ...

    try {
        Validate(el);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        errors.Add(e);
    }

    // ...
}

if(erros.Any()) {
    throw errors; // somente objetos do tipo Exception podem ser disparados com throw.
}
```

Como eu disparo múltiplas exceções?

Comment: Não sei se entendi a explicação do problema. A conclusão do que teria que fazer para resolvê-lo e talvez por isso a pergunta em si não parece fazer sentido e a resposta seria "não dá". Talvez por não entender o problema não consiga ver a motivação pra tentar fazer isto.

Comment: Exceções devem ser utilizadas para controle de fluxo? (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48458/41056)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isso me parece um erro conceitual no código.

Aparentemente você está usando exceções para tratar validações e isso não só é errado como é muito ruim, é um extremo mal uso do mecanismo de exceções.

Deixando isto de lado a resposta curta para sua pergunta é: **Não é possível.**

Exceções são para, como o próprio nome diz, casos excepcionais e não para validação de dados ou tarefas similares.

Supondo que você não queira consertar o código e deixar de usar estas exceções, o máximo que poderá fazer é passar essa lista de exceções até a camada de interface gráfica e lá fazer algo para mostrar as mensagens de deseja (ou fazer o que bem entende).

Mas, desta forma, não é possível capturá-las usando um bloco `catch`.

Ainda é possível disparar uma `AggregateException` com base na lista de exceções e capturá-la. Algo como:

Para disparar:

```
if(erros.Any()) {
    throw new AggegateException("Mensagem", errors);
}
```

Para capturar:

```
catch (AggregateException ae) 
{
    ae.Handle((x) =>
    {
        // Todas as exceções dentro de 'ae' passarão por este bloco
        return true; // Isso impede a parada do código
    });
}
```

Talvez seja interessante ler estas publicações:

- [Melhor maneira de lidar com Exceptions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13303/18246)
- [Devo usar um "try-catch" para identificar se uma senha está errada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141899/18246)
- [Exceções devem ser usadas para controle de fluxo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48410/18246)
- [Exceções consomem muito processamento. Verdade ou lenda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5888/18246) (essa não tá relacionada diretamente, mas acho bom ver)

---

Código funcional do exemplo com `AggregateException`. [Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qN0NIN)

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            FazerAlgo();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            ae.Handle((ex) =>
                      {
                          WriteLine(ex.Message);
                          return true;
                      });
        }
    }

    static void FazerAlgo()
    {
        throw new AggregateException("", new List<Exception>
                                     {
                                         new Exception("Erro 1"),
                                         new Exception("Erro 2")
                                     });
    }
}
```

Comment: Legal. Pode falar mais um pouco sobre não lidar com exceções para validação? Por exemplo, meu método `Gravar`, da classe, chama o método `Validar`, da classe também, como minha view ficaria sabendo do erro que ocorreu para interromper o fluxo e mostrar o erro de validação?

Comment: @vnbrs Você precisa desenvolver com isso em mente. Existem muitas técnicas. Por exemplo, no ASP.NET MVC, são feitas validações no controller, com base em anotações (`attributes`) que são definidas nas classes. Existe o fluent validation e por aí vai indo. Sobre este dois método estarem na mesma classe: não posso dizer que isto é errado e nem que não vai funcionar, mas a validação deveria mais perto da UI e menos perto do funcionamento. Se você começar as separar as responsabilidades e distribuí-las entre as "camadas" da aplicação vai notar que fica mais fácil fazer este tipo de validação.

Answer (score 8):

Caso realmente queira lançar várias exceções de uma vez para o chamador do código, use a classe `AggregateException`, ela recebe uma lista de `Exception`.

Adaptei seu código como **exemplo**:

```
List<Exception> errors = new List<Exception>();

foreach (Foo el in arr) {
    // ...

    try {
        Validate(el);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        errors.Add(e);
    }

    // ...
}

if(erros.Any()) {
    throw new AggregateException(
        "Vários erros ocorreram durante a execução do método.",
        errors)
}
```

Comment: Eu votei na resposta porque me parece que responde a pergunta, só quero dizer que acho isto muito raro de ser útil, quase sempre tem gambiarra nisto.