# Como usar try e catch com PHP?

Tags: php, exceção, try-catch

Estou com uma dúvida sobre como aplicar o `try` e `catch` em um método.

```
public function cadastrarUsuarios(parametros){

 mysqli_query($this->conexao,"INSERT....");

// Aqui que vem a dúvida

    try{
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($this->conexao) > 0){
           $_SESSION["Sucesso"] = time() + 3;
           return "<script>window.location.href='pagina.php';</script>";
        }else{
           $_SESSION["Erro"] = time() + 3;
           $erro = '';
          throw new Exception($erro);
        }
      }catch (Exception $erro){
            return $erro->getMessage();
     }
    }
```

A chamada do método se faz em outra página e no topo:

```
 include("classes/metodosClass.php");
 $metodos = new metodosClass();

 if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Submit") == "Cadastrar"){    
   ....    
  echo $metodos->cadastrarUsuarios(parametros);    
 }
```

Está correto a forma como está sendo aplicado o `try` e `catch`?

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar [Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58536/para-que-servem-os-blocos-try-catch-e-quando-devem-ser-utilizados/424523#424523)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neste caso não há razão alguma para fazer isso. Está [usando exceção para controle de fluxo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101), e da pior forma possível. Se uma exceção será capturada na própria função que é lançada está errado em 100% dos casos. A exceção é uma forma de desviar a execução do código de forma distante de onde está.

Se a exceção for capturada fora costuma estar errado na maioria dos casos que as pessoas fazem. Se usado certo tem bem pouco `try-catch` no código. E [quase nunca capture a `Exception`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101).

Este caso seria mais simples assim:

```
public function cadastrarUsuarios(parametros) {
    mysqli_query($this->conexao,"INSERT....");
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($this->conexao) > 0) {
        $_SESSION["Sucesso"] = time() + 3;
        return "<script>window.location.href='pagina.php';</script>";
    } else {
        $_SESSION["Erro"] = time() + 3;
        return NULL;
    }
}

$resultado = $metodos->cadastrarUsuarios(parametros);
if (is_null($resultado)) echo "deu erro";
else echo $resultado;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Exception/FlowControl.php)

No caso de PHP poderia não usar `NULL`, poderia ser um booleano. Na verdade qualquer coisa que não seja o esperado, até mesmo poderia usar a *string* vazia se for garantido que em condição normal nunca teria um resultado assim, mas tenho dúvidas se isso pode ser garantido neste caso.

Veja [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Também:

- [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101)
- [Devo usar um "try-catch" para identificar se uma senha está errada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141899/101)
- [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101)