# Para que serve um destrutor?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, destrutor

Em algumas linguagens, classes possuem métodos **destrutores**.

Nas que eu já vi, ele é declarado como um construtor com o sinal **~** na frente. Algo como:

```cpp
public class Foo
{
    public ~Foo()
    {
        //Fazer algo
    }
}
```

Para que servem métodos destrutores? Qual a necessidade de criá-los?

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9078/101

Comment: @bigown Acho que a resposta que foi escolhida não responde a minha pergunta. A outra até responde, mas talvez fosse uma boa ideia esperar por outras respostas. Não achas?

Comment: Relacionado: [Para que serve um construtor?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/3117)

Comment: @JéfersonBueno e a minha responde? Aí é duplicada.

Comment: Serve para as pessoas que chegaram até a sua pergunta vejam que existe um assunto relacionado (ou complementar) e já podem emendar a leitura do outro tópico. Além disso, ela fica em "destaque" nos links ao lado abaixo de "Vinculado". Tornando essa linkagem mais fácil.

Comment: @bigown num geral, responde. Embora ela seja específica para C#, dá pra ter uma noção. Se quiseres eu posso marcá-la como duplicada.

Comment: @Math entendido. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Métodos `Destrutores` servem para liberar a memória alocada dinamicamente pela classe, para eliminar as referências a ela, quando não existir.

Em Linguagens de programação que tem o `Garbage Collector`, não se faz necessário o uso de métodos destrutores, pois o `Garbage Collector` se encarrega de fazer isso.

A necessidade de cria-los, é em casos em que a linguagem não tem o `Garbage Collector`, e se faz necessário destruir a classe após sua utilização, para que não fique ocupando mémoria.

Em linguagens que tem o `Garbage Collector`, só se faz necessário o uso, quando da utilização de recursos não gerenciados.

> Os tipos mais comuns de recursos não gerenciados são objetos que envolvem recursos do sistema operacional, como arquivos, janelas, conexões de rede ou conexões de bancos de dados. [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/498928w2.aspx)

Nesses casos o `Garbage Collector` não sabe como liberar e limpar o recurso não gerenciado.

Nem todas linguagens fazem uso do sinal `~` para designar um destrutor.

Em `PHP` por exemplo é usado `__`:

```
void __destruct ( void )
```

`Python`

```
def __del__(self):
```

Answer (score 0):

Eles são métodos especiais que contém limpar o código para o objeto. Você não pode chamá-los explicitamente no seu código, como são chamados implicitamente pelo GC. Em C# têm mesmo nome que o nome da classe precedidos pelo sinal ~. Exemplo:

```
class MyClass{

~ MyClass(){
.....
  }
}
```

Em VB.NET, destruidores são implementadas, substituindo o método Finalize da classe System.Object.

**Por que usar?**

> Quando voce for escrever objetos que manipulam recursos não
>   gerenciados[Para destruir os recursos não gerenciados]