# Como criar uma classe com atributos e métodos em C++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, método

Em Java eu sei como faz, mas em C/C++ é pouco diferente então  como criar uma classe com atributos e métodos C++?

Estou utilizando CodeBlocks.

Quando crio uma classe em C++ ele cria dois arquivos um `.h` e outro `.cpp`

- Arquivo.h

  ```
  #ifndef TETES_H
  #define TETES_H


  class Tetes
  {
      public:
          Tetes();
          virtual ~Tetes();
      protected:
      private:
  };

  #endif // TETES_H
  ```
- Arquivo.cpp

  ```
  #include "Tetes.h"

  Tetes::Tetes()
  {
      //ctor
  }

  Tetes::~Tetes()
  {
      //dtor
  }
  ```

Onde vou definir os atributos e os métodos e também onde crio o construtor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O exemplo colocado na pergunta (após edição) indica uma diferença fundamental entre o Java e o C++ (C não permite ter classes).

A declaração da estrutura de dados normalmente é feita separada da implementação dos métodos (é possível fazer a implementação na própria declaração, mas há desvantagens em fazer isto (há vantagens também, então depende do caso para escolher um ou outro).

Em geral a declaração é colocada em arquivos *header* e a implementação em `.cpp`. Mas não precisa ser assim. Novamente tem vantagens e desvantagens em cada um. Em Java a declaração e implementação é uma coisa só.

Os atributos são sempre colocados na declaração. O exemplo abaixo com comentários dá um ideia da diferença da declaração e da implementação. Afinal atributos só fazem parte da estrutura de dados.

Os métodos são declarados junta da declaração da classe também. Em alguns casos é possível ter sua implementação *inline*. Isso dá alguma flexibilidade mas expõe o fonte (os cabeçalhos com as declarações são sempre necessários na compilação para consumir uma classe em algum código) e exige uma compilação do código toda vez que ele for usado (simplificadamente é isso).

Para evitar as desvantagens acima e eventualmente obter outras características é muito comum que a implementação dos métodos sejam separadas. É o que está no `.cpp`.

O construtor não é diferente, é declarado também durante a declaração da classe (geralmente `.h` ou `.hpp`) e a implementação pode ser ali mesmo ou, o mais comum, no `.cpp`. No exemplo já está tudo certo, só falta escrever o corpo dele, [se é que precisa de um construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). O destrutor provavelmente precisa menos ainda.

Lembre-se que a em C++, assim como o C, a [assinatura do método ou função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) é diferente da sua implementação.

Cada membro deve ser colocado no bloco de acordo coma visibilidade que ele deve ter.

Um exemplo simples retirado dessa [fonte](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/):

```
#include <iostream> //carrega um arquivo de definições (semelhante mas diferente do import)
using namespace std; //permite acessar os membros deste "pacote" diretamente

class Rectangle {
    int width, height; //são privados por default
  public: //tudo abaixo é público
    Rectangle(int, int); //note só a assinatura do construtor (poderia ser inline também)
    int area() { return width * height; }//implementação inline; pode escolher o + indicado
}; //declaração tem ; em alguns casos ela fica melhor em um header .hpp

Rectangle::Rectangle(int a, int b) { //implementação do construtor separado da declaração
    width = a;
    height = b;
}

int main () { //essa parte é só para testar
  Rectangle rect (3,4); //instanciação, tem outras formas de fazer o mesmo
  Rectangle rectb (5,6);
  cout << "rect area: " << rect.area() << endl;
  cout << "rectb area: " << rectb.area() << endl;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/Class.cpp).

Além da sintaxe ligeiramente diferente, a semântica das classes em C++ é significativamente diferente do Java.

Comment: o que seria essa parte `Tetes::~Tetes()`?

Comment: É o destrutor. É outra linguagem, funciona um pouco diferente, mas é parecido: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75613/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9078/101

Comment: @Maniero Onde entra a interface?

Comment: @Khyser em lugar algum, a pergunta não é sobre isto.

Comment: @Maniero Mais que audácia