# Destrutor em C++

Tags: c++

Ao resolver algumas questões em C++, me deparei com o código:

```
class MinhaClasse{
private:
       int a;
public:
     MinhaClasse(int b){
        a = b;
       ImprimeA();
       };
    ~MinhaClasse(){
       IncrementaA();
       ImprimeA();
     };
   void IncrementaA(){
       a++;
       };
   void ImprimeA(){
    printf("[%d]", a);
    };
  };
    
 int main(){
   MinhaClasse * mClasseD = new MinhaClasse(1);
   MinhaClasse mClasseE(10);
   return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
[1][10][11]
```

Porém, ao retirar o destrutor `~MinhaClasse()`, a saída passa a ser:

```
[1][10]
```

Li alguns conceitos sobre destrutor e algumas perguntas, sobre o tema, entre elas:

1. [Pra que serve um destrutor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75613/para-que-serve-um-destrutor)
2. [Dúvida sobre função em C++ que funciona como um destrutor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/338977/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-c-que-funciona-como-um-destrutor)

Entretanto sigo sem entender muito bem este código, *por que ao retirar o destrutor minha saída muda?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos ver o seu `main`:

```
 int main(){
   MinhaClasse * mClasseD = new MinhaClasse(1);    // A
   MinhaClasse mClasseE(10);                       // B
   return 0;                                       // C
}
```

Na linha A, você cria uma instância no *heap* e a atribui em um ponteiro. Como ela está no *heap* é sua responsabilidade desalocá-la explicitamente.

Na linha B, você cria uma instância no *stack* e nesse caso o compilador coloca o gerenciamento de memória automaticamente.

Quando a função termina (no C), todas as variáveis no *stack* são destruídas. Como a classe `MinhaClasse` tem um destrutor e isso significa que o objeto `mClasseE` será destruído, o compilador vai colocar uma chamada ao destrutor dele para poder limpar o *stack*.

Entretanto, no caso do `mClasseD`, a responsabilidade de destruir o objeto é do programador (com `delete mClasseD;`). Mas como você não fez isso, o resultado é que o objeto não é destruído e torna-se um *memory leak*.

Veja mais [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/132) para entender o que exatamente é o *heap* e o *stack*.

Comment: Entendi Victor! Obrigado mesmo! Vou dar uma estudada em Heap e Stack, Obrigado mais uma vez

Answer (score 4):

Porque ao sair do escopo principal o objeto `mClasseE` morre, assim chamando o destrutor da sua classe, que incrementa e imprime, como o valor de `a` era 10 mostra 11.

Já o objeto `mClasseD` não chama o destrutor porque você criou ele com o [**new**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/cpp/new-operator-cpp?view=vs-2019) e o destrutor nesse caso não é chamado, você deve "limpar" a memoria usando o **delete** para esse objeto porque senão o seu código terá vazamento de memoria. Quando o **delete** for chamado para o objeto `mClasseD` o destrutor da classe será chamado.