# O que são Desconstrutores?

Tags: c#, tupla, record-types

Ao estudar sobre Records em C# 9 foi apresentado o recurso `Deconstruct()` em que o objeto é atribuído a uma Tupla. O que é um `Deconstruct()`? Ele remove a referência do objeto fazendo com que ele deixe de existir? Quando usá-lo? Qual a importância do uso deste recurso?

Comment: Onde viu isso? Tem contexto? Não me lembro de nada geral da linguagem sobre isso. Até tem destrutor, mas não isso.https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9078/101

Comment: @Maniero editei a pergunta para que fique mais claro.

Comment: Aí já é outra coisa completamente diferente.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Existem algumas situações que você pode querer que um determinado objeto seja desconstruído com determinados valores atribuídos para variáveis.

Descontruir não é relacionado com destruir. Construir é pegar partes e fazer virar uma coisa só, e destruir é sumir com tudo que existe. Desconstruir é pegar esse todo que foi construído em algum momento e voltar ter partes separadas.

Sabe na gastronomia quando se fala que uma determinada comida é descontruída? As suas partes está separada, por exemplo, um hamburger onde está no prato o pão, do lado a carne, e mais pra lá o alface e tomate, etc. Não tem aquele jeito de sanduíche.

Então para criar um mecanismo automático que o compilador faça a desconstrução quando precisa criar um algoritmo que determine que variáveis ele gerará e como os valores serão jogados nelas. É o oposto do construtor que tem variáveis que serão usadas para receber valores e guardar no objeto em campos específicos.

E isso foi feito introduzindo um conceito diferente do que se estava acostumado em C#. O mecanismo usou uma forma de [*duck typing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/574146/101) (não exatamente), então se o compilador achar um método chamado `Deconstruct()` com uma ou mais variáveis como parâmetros do tipo [`out`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101), então o tipo em questão está habilitado a fazer uma desconstrução.

Pegando o exemplo da documentação:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Person {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    public Person(string fname, string mname, string lname, string cityName, string stateName) {
        FirstName = fname;
        MiddleName = mname;
        LastName = lname;
        City = cityName;
        State = stateName;
    }

    public void Deconstruct(out string fname, out string lname) {
        fname = FirstName;
        lname = LastName;
    }

    public void Deconstruct(out string fname, out string mname, out string lname) {
        fname = FirstName;
        mname = MiddleName;
        lname = LastName;
    }

    public void Deconstruct(out string fname, out string lname, out string city, out string state) {
        fname = FirstName;
        lname = LastName;
        city = City;
        state = State;
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void Main() {
        var p = new Person("John", "Quincy", "Adams", "Boston", "MA");
        var (fName, lName, city, state) = p; //essa sintaxe é de desconstrução chamando o terceiro método
        WriteLine($"Hello {fName} {lName} of {city}, {state}!");
        var (nome, sobrenome) = p; //aqui chama o primeiro método de desconstrução.
        WriteLine($"{nome} {sobrenome}");
        var (pnome, _, unome) = p; //aqui chama o segundo método de desconstrução.
        WriteLine($"{pnome} {unome}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/agqiGm) (funcionará quando eles atualizarem o compilador). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rUP608). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Deconstruct.cs).

O primeiro método já conhece, é o construtor. Os outros são desconstrutores. Note que pode ter vários desde que a [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) seja diferente. Então no momento que faz a desconstrução de acordo com a quantidade de variáveis e seus tipos, se tiver, um método diferente será chamado.

Perceba que o que o método faz é pegar as variáveis que serão desconstruídas e são passadas como `out`, ou seja, cada variável é usada para receber um valor e não passar um. Veja no *link* acima como funciona um parâmetro `out`. Então ele faz o processamento que tem que fazer, em geral é só pegar um campo e mandar para o parâmetro e isso mandará o valor para a variável que usou na desconstrução. Nada impede que tenha outros processamentos mais complexos, só é obrigado que todas variáveis de parâmetros sejam inicializadas ali dentro do método.

A função desse método é só processar algo no objeto e jogar os valores para quem pediu, se for dentro dos padrões estabelecidos.

Dá para criar esses [métodos até como extensão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136913/101) que o compilador consegue fazer a desconstrução.

Eu acho isso muito bom para tornar certos códigos muito mais curtos e reduzir *boilerplate*. E essa é principal vantagem. Experimenta tirar os desconstrutores e escrever o código do `Main()` que dê o mesmo resultado, depois me conta. Sem isso tudo funciona, mas escreve mais código para acessar os dados.

Em alguns casos pode até eliminar os *getters*, e só deixar pegar valores do objeto desta forma.

É um recurso de leitura, nada é mexido no objeto (até poderia se quisesse fazer, mas raro ser útil), reforço que ele não destrói nada.

Se estiver curioso como isso é compilado, seria algo assim (só o segundo):

```
public static void Main() {
    Person p = new Person("John", "Quincy", "Adams", "Boston", "MA");
    string nome;
    string sobrenome;
    p.Deconstruct(out nome, out sobrenome);
    WriteLine(nome + " " + sobrenome);
}
```

Veja [no **SharpLab** como realmente fica](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=).

Um detalhe importante é que não foi atribuído para uma tupla. A sintaxe é uma forma justamente de desconstrução de uma tupla ou outro objeto que permite fazer a desconstrução. Parece uma tupla mas é só uma forma de declarar ou utilizar várias variáveis que receberão valores frutos da desconstrução.

Tem vários recursos que se as pessoas aprendem usar poderiam fazer códigos mais curtos e expressivos. Tem uns truques com *cast* que pode ajudar bastante também, mas é outro assunto.

Answer (score -2):

Basicamente, o que um Construtor faz é criar um novo objeto de determinado tipo com determinados parâmetros (aqui estou optando pelo construtor padrão, pois não possui parâmetros).

Então, o que o Desconstrutor deve fazer é desconstruir o objeto de volta às suas partes originais.

Para ser específico, você tem o controle de especificar como você gostaria que o objeto fosse desconstruído.

fonte: http://www.macoratti.net/18/11/c_novers72.htm

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: Lembrando que também não queremos um copia-e-cola aqui no Stack Overflow. Pode haver citações na sua resposta, mas é importante que seja **sua** resposta.

Comment: como assim uma resposta Copiada e colada não vale?! Ainda assim seria uma resposta valida...
Muitas respostas aqui são Copiadas e coladas...

Comment: @EduMendonça Acho que o problema é fazer simplesmente um mero Ctrl-C Ctrl-V de outro lugar, sem acrescentar nada. A [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) é bem clara quanto a isso: "*Não copie o texto completo de fontes externas; em vez disso, use as respectivas palavras e ideias para apoiar as suas próprias*" - tem também [esta discussão no Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5430/112052)